# When Should a Question be Changed to Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I have asked a question:

*[#1039 - "Can anyone recommend a perimeter SPAM filtering service?"](https://serverfault.com/questions/1039/can-anyone-recommend-a-perimeter-spam-filtering-service)*

I have since discovered there is no single right answer, however I find great benefit to the multitude of good answers.

Is this now a community wiki?  How do I know, what is the criteria for marking a question community wiki?

[Return to FAQ Index](https://serverfault.com/questions/8324/how-does-serverfault-work-the-community-faq)

Answer (score 7):

Here is the information on community wiki questions lifted from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128434/what-are-community-wiki-posts-in-stackoverflow)

### Why have Community Wiki posts?

One of the goals of Stackoverflow is to be a continually evolving source of good information. Community Wiki posts help enhance the wiki aspect of the site.

### How do Community Wiki posts work?

Community Wiki posts work by transferring ownership of the post from the original author to the community. They make the post easier to edit and maintain by a wider group of users, but they do not contribute to any user's reputation. Community Wiki posts are marked as community wiki.

Some of the key features are:

- Community Wiki posts are owned by the Community User, not by any individual user.
- A much lower reputation is needed to edit a community wiki post.
- Voting on a community wiki post (up or down) does not affect any user's reputation.
- The original author still gets badges based on community posts.
- The original author keeps the reputation gained (or lost) before their post entered community mode.

### How does a post become a Community Wiki post?

There are several ways a question or answer can enter community wiki mode, and most of these ways will occur automatically based on the rules of the system.

Posts enter community wiki mode when:

- The body of the post has been edited by four different people.
- The post has been edited five times by the original owner.
- The question is initially asked, if the author checks the community wiki checkbox.
  -The question generates more than 30 answers. In this case all answers and the question will enter community mode, including any future answers.

### When should I set my post/answer to Community mode from the outset?

I feel that the following types of posts and answers are best set to community mode from the get-go:

- Anything that could have have serverfault or sffaq tag applied.
- Any "official" type response to a serverfault or sofaq tagged question, such as the "official" answer to this question, or this answer.
- Polls - both the initial question, and the set of answers that users can upvote to cast their vote in the poll should be set to community mode. Not only will this keep rep-harvesting to a minimum, but I think people will be more likely to freely cast votes in polls if they know that someone is not gaining as a result. This could apply to posts like "What is your favorite X?", "What is the best Y?", and possibly even "Hidden features of Z".

### Miscellaneous

There is no way to reclaim your post back from community wiki mode. This is to prevent exploits and gaming of the system.
Rollbacks do not reverse any of the community wiki mode calculations.

Comment: You really should only include the link and not duplicate the content. I don't want to see sofaq/sffaq get fragmented and out of sync.

Comment: Well there really needs to be a clear decision as to whether we are duplicating FAQ's here, or pointing to SO. Users who are new here and have not heard of SO before may find going there to look at FAq's confusing. Also it may help users if FAQ's are customized for SF use, removing references to programming examples etc.

Comment: Think there ought to be separate FAQs here.  At the moment, the population of the site is familiar with SO, but as time goes on, that will be less and less true.  I think Jeff wants this site to develop it's own community, not just be the place you go when your tech question gets voted "not programming related" on SO.

Answer (score 4):

Lo these many days ago, when the knowledge of fire was young and many still lived who remembered the Stack Overflow beta, there was a great shadow on the land. For some of the people though that Goodness was measured in technical prowess only, and other sought joy in jokes, popularity, comics, and other things of a frivolous nature.

Bad blood arose between the tribes, and many Users Voiced strongly worded opinions, teeth were gnashed, beards were pulled, much dander was seen raised high, and discouraging words were heard where they should not be heard.

But in time, peace was forged, and it was agreed by many that the joyous should go forth to babble of best comments, and worst managers without constraint yet would not seek to measure their accomplishments by these things, but only by works of a studious nature.

And so it was.

But, my friends, the land welcomes new people every day, and this agreement must be continuously renewed lest the trying times come again. So go forth and teach this history as I have chanted it to you.

Answer (score 1):

Community wiki doesn't really have anything to do with whether a question has a single right answer or not.

Community wiki just means that:

- People with a lower rep can edit it
- You don't gain rep for upvotes on it

Based on the precedents set on SO, a question should probably be community wiki if it is a poll type question or a fun somewhat off-topic question (to prevent people from gaining a bunch of rep for posting a good programmer cartoon, for instance).  FAQ type questions (like this one) should also be CW.

I don't really see any reason for the question you linked to to be community wiki.