# Is it acceptable to post jobs in this forum?

Tags: support, jobs

I am a technical recruiter in the Greater Puget Sound area, and I feel this would be a great place to post my clients' needs.

Is it acceptable to post jobs in this forum?

Comment: Absolutely not!

Comment: Not on stackoverflow.com, but see http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Post jobs at http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer

Comment: I agree with the +1 for asking first. Also, if you come over to Meta and see this question, you should know that downvotes on Meta typically mean "I disagree," rather than "this question is of low quality." Your question is a valid one, even though the answer is "no."

Comment: -1 for "forum["](http://foo.bar)

Comment: @Wont -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stackoverflow-a-forum

Answer (score 18):

If you post job advertisments, or any advertisment really, on Stack Overflow not only will your post be deleted quickly, but if you continue to do so you will be banned from the site.

Stack Overflow already has a job board you might consider using, although they may have special rules for recruiters, so make sure you understand before you post:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/employer

Answer (score 5):

The job board's great, though - I've found a ton of great candidates with it, always passionate about tech, know their stuff, and no jerks. Which is awesome, in and of itself.

Answer (score 3):

No, stackoverflow is meant for programming help and questions. Not for job postings.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully not. This would kill this place and make it unusable because of all the spammy irrelevant posts.