# Can I post a potential consulting gig?

Tags: discussion, jobs, referrals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it acceptable to post jobs in this forum?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94653/is-it-acceptable-to-post-jobs-in-this-forum)

I may have a consulting gig lead.  A large corporation I deal with may be interested in implementing some stuff I have done, for MY business, in their corporation.

I don't have the cycles to help them.  My stuff is Ruby On Rails.  They don't have Ruby on Rails expertise,  but they really want to implement what I've done for my business within their IT department.  This corporation is crucial to my business, and I want to help them in any way I can.

So, I want to post the potential opportunity for someone to talk to these people, and see if they can land a consulting gig to help them implement my RoR stuff in their environment.  If they can secure the gig,  I would have to send them all the details of what I've done in RoR.  They'd then determine how they can modify what I've done for their environment.

Is there an appropriate way to convey this opportunity in the Stack Overflow community?

Comment: Yes. Go to Careers.SE and post a job opening.

Answer (score 5):

## [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)

<sub>This wouldn't be an appropriate thing to post as a question on Stack Overflow, but is exactly what Careers was made for.</sub>