# Are Thank you's at ends of questions acceptable?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, noise-reduction

This is a question from an editor-in-training.

Are "Thank you"'s at ends of questions acceptable?

Thank you!

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). I personally try to remove "fluff" as I see it.

Comment: I just edited a question to remove the "Good morning" from the beginning.  The same post also had "Thanks and regards" at the end.  If I see that, should I remove it as well?

Comment: I personally would. You can take a look at [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6487878/revisions) I made and the opening and closing I removed.

Comment: Thanks aren't removed automatically but only because it's not (yet) practical.  Feel free to remove them by hand.

Comment: Remove it if you are in there making other edits. Don't make an edit for the sole purpose of removing thanks, though: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/

Comment: Related: [The Stack Exchange sites are ***not*** forums](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) (fora?). They are [think tanks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As reported by Jeff Atwood in [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989) salutations are automatically removed.
He also added that "the *thanks* parts at the end of posts are much more difficult/risky to detect, so we are not touching those for now."

The point is that the question text should focus on the question itself; what is extra should not be added, or posted as comment, if it helps in someway.

Phrases like "thank you," "any help is appreciated," or "I hope somebody can help me" don't add anything to the question but says something that seems implicit; they should be removed, in the same way signatures or tag lines are removed.

Comment: it's more hurtful to have extra text at the top (where everyone starts reading, and where excerpts are taken from) than the bottom. I wouldn't mind removing "thanks" at the bottom but it also feels a little.. mean-spirited. Or at least more so than simply removing "hello" at the beginning.

Comment: I take them off when I'm editing other things, but usually my edit comment is something like "Removing unnecessary politeness (sorry!)"