# What site can you use if you have a "gimme teh codez" question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, asking-questions

On Stack Overflow, there are quite a few questions, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658399/adding-checked-products-to-a-custom-php-basket (10K link), where the OP wants you to implement things for him/her, without really asking a question.

So, when you face this problem, there are two solutions:

- Do the work yourself, and add a specific question if you happen to have one, like [Pekka](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/138112/pekka) suggested:

> I suggest you try for yourself [implement the feature / fix the problem] and come back if you have specific, answerable questions

- Go to a website designed for this purpose.

Do you know if such a website exists?

Comment: How about Yahoo Answers?

Comment: If such a website existed I would not send the person there, it is just encouraging the behavoir.

Comment: For [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658399/adding-checked-products-to-a-custom-php-basket), you have a much higher change to get a satisfying answer on SO, so I understand that the OP did that. I'm looking for a website about programming related questions, and where you expect decent answers. That might not exist tough.

Comment: Yes, Get/Rent-A-Coder are dealing with these questions.

Comment: I don't think any forum, group or community would entertain such a question unless a monetary transaction was offered. Sometimes, if I can honestly tell that the OP is just completely and utterly stuck at the beginning despite effort, I'll provide a bit of a 'wire frame'. But, that's the extent of it.

Comment: Yes, stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Mobinga: Uh, no.

Comment: Good review by Dan Appleman about major online job/consulting web sites : http://www.examiner.com/article/odesk-guru-elance-and-rentacoder-are-they-worth-it

Comment: Send them to [gimmetehcodez.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108552/197901)! (link points to Mad Scientist's answer ;)

Comment: Try Careers2.0?

Comment: Try the "gimme teh codez" subreddit? https://www.reddit.com/r/gimmeCodez/

Comment: Related: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

There is no SE site for that, and I can't imagine that there ever will be one. A Q&A site where people answer questions without any monetary compensation can't work if the ones asking spend pretty much no effort on their problem and the answerers are expected to do the whole work for free.

If you want someone to do the whole work for you, you just need to hire someone and pay them to do that.

Comment: "A Q&A site where people answer questions without any monetary compensation can't work if ... the answerers are expected to do the whole work for free." Sounds exactly like S.O. to me and yet S.O. is working and people are giving away millions and millions of dollars worth of consulting for free. I don't see how the questioner having put more or less effort into it changes that equation. I'm not suggesting S.O. allow those types of questions. Just saying I don't see it as a reason that it can't work.

Comment: @gman Solving a problem is very different from just writing the whole code. One has focus on teaching, the other is just doing work. SO focuses on solving problems and explaining

Comment: @gman, I think [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115/493669) explains why it doesn't work (in the long run). Although the discussion there is about Stack Exchange being a forum or not, I think there is a big parallel and the same arguments apply for this question. Especially the reference to the [chat room/forum problem](http://scobleizer.com/?p=5980) is quite interesting. It very well explains that it "_can't work if the ones asking spend pretty much no effort on their problem and the answerers are expected to do the whole work for free_".