# Most recent bad behaviours of Stack Overflow users I have faced

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, down-votes, self-answer

I have a serious question about Stack Overflow, and I think Meta Stack Overflow is a good place to make myself correct on my confusions.

As we know, Stack Overflow is a Q/A forum. But when I am asking questions, users in a group keep continuing to down-vote. After  I did edit, no one corrected their voting. Being a question-answer forum, when I am asking questions people behaving the way, that I did wrong - why so?

Another is, is it anywhere written in Stack Overflow that people who post questions, couldn't answer their own questions?

Now if my question is not clear to someone, putting down-vote, whereas none of the other telling that. So it seems there is a gang of people who does this regularly. Why is Stack Overflow not taking care of these?

In Stack Overflow, there should be a strict line to say to everybody, so that, none of any to think the other/opposite people as the same knowledgeable like themselves. There is a mixture of knowledgeable people present. It is not mandatory that a person `X` always should have the same knowledge like the other `Y`.

People who are asking always get less respect than the ones who are answering. If you see each of the people account, you would definitely find that a `60K rep` person got the 70% of the rep, answering such simple but basic questions. But when they crossed 1000 rep they started to think badly of others.

The same happened with one of my question on Stack Overflow - [How to get the reference alive to the older one, when there is a second exception in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788241/how-to-get-the-reference-alive-to-the-older-one-when-there-is-a-second-exceptio).

Here I have posted my own answer, and that one has been converted to a comment - why so?

Please help me if I am wrong and where I am wrong.

Comment: `So it seems there is a gang of people who did these regularly` - proof please.

Comment: Your post is a bit hard to follow. You seem to be trying to address two issues: downvotes & self-answers. It would be easier to follow if you stuck to just one of these issues, and made another question for the other. (And as Oded says: what makes you think you have a group after you? That's very unlikely.)

Comment: Okay! can you open the link i have given there and please do read the chat in the main thread and you will come to know the fact. And they in my other posts also said that they have more reputation,so they can do what they want - that was not said,but the intention comes out like the way.

Comment: No. Incorrect. SO is **not** a forum.

Comment: *"And they in my other posts also said that they have more reputation,so they can do what they want - that was not said,but the intention comes out like the way*"...so did they say that (link please) or didn't they? If they actually did, such comments might be flagable.

Comment: So help me what `SO` is ?

Comment: I think we might simply have a bit of a language barrier here. Which might be the cause of some initially unclear questions (this one being an example) which then gather downvotes. And Stack Overflow is a Q&A site. People around here get a bit itchy about the word "forum", which SO is not.

Comment: That's the thing they have deleted such comments immediately. But you would really come to know if you go to the link i have pasted in the description.

Comment: @user1878162 A website where you ask good questions and get good answers, ask bad questions and get downvotes.

Comment: @user1878162 I have visited that link and see no comments which cross any boundary of inappropriate behaviour.

Comment: @Bart Several comments appear to have been deleted

Comment: @Asad Might be. A mod will be able to tell.

Comment: @Asad Okay, with you I am going to give some post as an example where you can see what i am trying to say, just give me a moment.

Comment: Funny how the account linked to your account here ([this](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1776751/pythonlikeyou)) isn't the same as the owner of the post you gave a link to. Creating a new user to circumvent a ban isn't really a good idea.

Comment: So you have two Stack Overflow accounts at least?

Comment: Do you have a coherently written question?

Comment: @JackManey i didn't get you.

Comment: Can you please ask a comprehensible question, instead of running some text through Google Translate several times? Also, the string "i" is not a word in the English language.

Comment: @JackManey You have a point, but could you dial down the snark? I'm not sure the OP will get it and some clear explanation might go a long way.

Comment: @Bart - I'm being as direct and non-snarky as possible.

Comment: @JackManey english is my third language,but on the platform of programming I think that language not matters anymore, A programmer can understand the things by looking at the code only.

Comment: 0_o "A programmer can understand the things by looking at the code only." Yes, that explains why there's no need for documentation. Oh, wait...

Comment: maybe true sometimes but it's definitely much easier when there's a clear explanation with what you're trying to achieve. and the people answering questions are doing it on their own time so it's only fair to make it as easy as possible

Comment: @user1878162 Code will only illustrate what you have. It does not tell us what the problem is and what question you have. So language is important. Clarity is important. And your questions lack clarity in several cases. We can fix spelling and grammar mistakes, but we can't make a significantly unclear question a great one.

Comment: All were mentioned there, people did many more edits and my originality got lost. there are more than 1000 questions in `SO` where OP put only a single line. Got 90 + votes. So how SO policy forgot to prevent that `no-research` post.

Comment: @user1878162 Let's stay on the topic of your questions. The (possibly poor) questions of other users have no significance in this discussion. They are not "evidence" in any case you might think you have.

Comment: Yes, that's the pain. SO policy not works for all equally that was my intention to say. Now my account also got locked,saying my post have no vote, where as I can still see that there was plenty of questions which got average 10 votes in my account, This is the behavior i am talking about in SO with low reputation people. But the higher rep people might forgot that they also started with `1`. And education when falls into `vote` this is the basic things really would happen. Here people joined only to get rep in  pocket.

Comment: But I had felt bad not for rep, as multiple down vote causes next post to get lock.

Comment: You got suspended because of low quality contributions. This has temporarily set your rep back to 1. Your rep is not taken away and will return (if no other actions are taken) once the timed suspension expires.

Comment: Well, sort of. He got suspended because he created multiple accounts, in what moderators believe to be an attempt to bypass a post ban caused by low-quality contributions, or to pass upvotes between accounts. He broke the rules, in other words.

Comment: @user1878162 1) [You said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167033/most-recent-bad-behaviours-of-so-users-i-have-faced/167038#comment489552_167036) that this was your old account, and that you did not use it anymore. 2) [The account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1776751/pythonlikeyou) was not suspended because your "post have no vote", but because of voting irregularities (which means you were using this sockpuppet to upvote your other account)

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Sure, just quoting the blurb.

Comment: All guys. leave the discussion here. I am no more interested here to go any more, This is the end me with `SO`.

Comment: Yeah! there are more without vote place, atleast education and voting can't sit in one place, and that shouldn't be. If sit then it would happen!

Answer (score 22):

Let's go through this step by step.

> But when I am putting questions users in a group keep continuing
>   down-vote.

There is no evidence for this, since voting is anonymous.

> After that when I did edit,no one corrected the voting.

There are several suggestions here on Meta for features that make it easier to track posts you have downvoted. You should check them out and throw an upvote their way. That said, some people have the time to come back and look at posts that they downvoted, some people do not. There is no obligation to do so, however.

> Another is it anywhere written in SO that people who post
>   questions,couldn't put the answer of his/her questions?

There is no such rule; in fact, answering your own question is encouraged. As Brad has explained to you in his comment, your answer was unclear, and was mistaken for a clarification of your question.

> People who asking always getting less respect than the one who are
>   answering.

This is not true. There are several users who have collected a majority of their reputation from consistently asking answerable, on topic questions that show research effort. Nevertheless, it is important to realise that having your question answered is in itself a reward. The answerer gains no real world benefits from voluntarily solving problems, which is why there are greater rewards in terms of reputation for answering.

Comment: +1, explains everything in the post

Answer (score 6):

On your downvoted posts, there are comments on why they were downvoted. Read them, and also read the [How To Ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

You seem to be misunderstanding SO. [Stack Overflow is **not** a forum!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum) I think reading the FAQ and How To Ask guide will help you ask better questions and not get downvoted as much.

There is no "gang" or anything like that. People downvote your posts because they don't comply with the rules of Stack Overflow.

Your posts are very hard to read. There are many spelling and grammar mistakes, which makes it hard to help and attracts downvotes.

Also. Don't expect people to reverse their downvotes when you fix your question if they have already left the question and are gone. Write the good quality question **first**, so you don't have to edit it to make it better. Unless you tell someone that you fixed your post (in a comment), they will probably not come back and reverse the -1 later.

Furthermore, you seem to have two accounts.

- [How to get the reference alive to the older one, when there is a second exception in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788241/how-to-get-the-reference-alive-to-the-older-one-when-there-is-a-second-exceptio) (Question you linked)
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/1776751/pythonlikeyou (Your associated account)

That is not good. Please only make one account.

Comment: Yes, after that i have also did lot's to make it clear,but the vote was not reverted  back.

Comment: @user1878162 Ok, I edited my answer.

Comment: @user1878162: you can't expect them to be patrolling the questions. They don't get notified of edits. They won't know that you fixed it. Also, your questions aren't that great even after improvement. Please don't use SO as a place to dump all your code problems :/

Comment: see here also down vote started.

Comment: @user1878162 Please read the Meta FAQ. Downvotes here are sometimes used to indicate disagreement. Always read the FAQ. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: @user1878162 This is a very low quality question too. Again, read the comments on this question and you might see why your question has -1s

Comment: Look at the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018137/where-are-catch-and-throw-useful-in-ruby?rq=1). here what effort the users were put,nothing then how it got escaped from down-vote.

Comment: @user1878162 A.) That was asked a **long** time ago. Things have changed. B.) He explained his question and used good formatting. It was easy to read, unlike your questions with LOTS of spelling and grammar mistakes. C.) He explained why he thinks the keyword is useless.

Comment: Nothing to say - answerers getting up vote from which post, that post maker getting dumped.

Comment: "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1776751/pythonlikeyou (Your associated account)" that's the one I am not using. Which was my old account, I had some issue with my log in credentials thus I opened another account.

Comment: @user1878162 Well, don't. Don't make new accounts.

Comment: @user1878162 - Is this also one of your accounts: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1978517/dolovesky or just a relative? Please be honest with us here so that we can clean this up.

Comment: One more thing is that - `So` rules are contradictory. from the below which was missed there point me please - `

    Specific programming problems
    Software algorithms
    Coding techniques
    Software development tools` --- and obviously all also can't be put on the same questions

Comment: @user1878162 It means **one** of those.

Comment: @user1878162 Now you're just being disingenuous. Clearly that means you shouldn't post questions that *aren't* about any of those things, not that you have to post questions that are about all of those things.

Answer (score 5):

> As we know SO is a Q/A forum.

It's...not a forum. See [the About page for SO](https://stackoverflow.com/about) for some more clarification.

> ...But when I am putting questions users in a group keep continuing
>   down-vote. After that when I did edit,no one corrected the
>   voting.Being a question-answer forum,when I am putting questions
>   people behaving the way,that I did wrong - Why so?

What's the quality of your questions?  Just a quick glance at your SO profile shows me [135 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1776751/pythonlikeyou?tab=questions).  It's also the case that a handful of them are well under 0 upvotes, which indicates that the community disagreed with the quality of the question.

That may be disheartening in and of itself, but I wouldn't let that get you down - improve the questions you have by editing them and making them fit in-line with the FAQ.

> Here i have posted my answer,and that one has been deleted and put over the description - why so?

Self-answers should follow the standards of other answers on the site.  Merely answering it in a poor quality way would lead it to being downvoted/potentially deleted.

Comment: No my answer was reverted/restored back by a moderator.

Comment: And the moderator also locked my account,which is not fare.

Comment: Did you read the reason that it was locked?  (This is highly tangential to your question, by the way.)

Comment: @user1878162: don't call things "not fair" when you yourself violated the rules by creating a new account to counteract the temporary ban on your first account.

Comment: all such comments are vauge! I told you naa that if you search the forum you can get many more low quality questions, and the answerers also earned too much rep from that, this is the opposite with me. Once someone said why?? frequently down vote started.

Comment: ...can we *not* have this discussion in my global inbox?  Please?