# Unwanted downvotes to my answers

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, down-votes

Since the last couple of days, a gang of people continuously downvotes my completely working solutions. One of the examples is:

[Order a hash array by an array key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153553/order-a-hash-array-by-an-array-key/16153706#16153706)

Whenever I am answering they come to down-vote. Please help me to stop this act.

***Update:***

See below how down-voting occurred frequently on the same question continuously, see the pattern:

[image: vote down pattern]

Comment: It seems the downvotes have been explained/justified below your answer. Are you sure your answers aren't lacking? If so, flag one of them for moderator attention and use the "other" option. Briefly explain what you think is happening.

Comment: Related to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167033/most-recent-bad-behaviours-of-so-users-i-have-faced.  Specifically, `So it seems there is a gang of people who did these regularly`.

Comment: I flagged it,but no one responding. whereas down-vote made it invisible.

Comment: look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126863/how-can-i-logically-or-two-include-conditions-in-ruby

Comment: Your attitude is so very, very wrong for Stack Overflow. **All** downvotes are unwanted. You're going to have to learn to deal with them, or you're going to have a *very bad time here*.

Comment: Also note that your answer had a whopping **two** downvotes before you started drawing all kinds of negative attention with your attitude.

Comment: @meagar Technically I proved that my one is better than the others, still you arguing that my one is worst. means technical proof has no value. right?

Comment: @RubyLovely You received a mere two downvotes for that answer. And you have received extensive comments explaining to you what the problem is with your answer. You seem to work based on the assumption that you are completely correct. Perhaps take a step back and evaluate if that is truly the case. Try to learn from the comments. If you can then confirm once again that you are correct, ignore them and move on.

Comment: Must... resist... urge... to add... [conspiracy-theory] tag....

Comment: oooh... the irony..

Answer (score 22):

I think you may be misunderstanding things, here. People could down vote your content for many reasons; it looks like from the comments that people are disagreeing with what you are posting. That's certainly a legitimate reason to down vote.

I see absolutely no evidence of anything unseemly going on here; simply reactions to your posts. And I would not even think of using the word 'gang' to describe the number of people/votes involved.

I strongly recommend looking *inward* here, if you want to stop the down voting. Try to take what people are saying at their word and understand their disagreements with what you are posting. The best of us always seek improvement!

---

Regarding your update, I don't know how to put this gently, so: grow up. People will vote on your content. You are talking about a tiny handful of votes spread out over *hours*. Again: I see nothing even *remotely* improper here.

Comment: in my link I posted description,tell me where the improvement feedback, look this - **That output isn't sorted at all. It's the same output the OP already has. The point is that it needs to be sorted by slug.** - completely vague, output is simply like the OP needed.

Comment: @RubyLovely It is futile to discuss the particulars of whether/not the post(s) in question deserved down votes with me, here. My only statement here is that it is clear people disagreed that your answers were useful. That is a wholly-appropriate reason for down voting.

Comment: Even if you were right and they were wrong, that is not gang downvoting and not something that needs attention or correction. If (and that's a big if) you are right and they are wrong, ignore it and move on.

Comment: To add to Bart's answer, the third option is to explain why their comments are not correct, or how you have fixed the post to address them.  Do so constructively.  Don't assume that they are being malicious, or that they're out to get you.  Assume they either found a mistake you need to fix, or they thought they found a mistake but were themselves mistaken.  If you're polite, odds are you can discover the truth together, fix the answer if needed, and then remove the downvotes.  If you insult them, don't even consider that they could have a point, and remain hostile, nothing good will come.

Comment: Based on what metrics they  are saying my code is worst. does it go logically or forcibly?

Comment: @RubyLovely That is an excellent topic to constructively discuss in the comments of your answers. Not here.

Comment: @Servy why you all telling same? Did you read that blurred answer I linke,everything is I explained.proved it mathematically things are going good,better then the other answer,still getting down-vote.

Comment: @RubyLovely Again: This is *not* the place to discuss the (in)correctness of your post. Nor is the *way* you are doing it the way that is going to get you any good results, I am afraid.

Comment: @AndrewBarber as you are an moderator, I want you to look into the same.so please see my **UPDATE**.

Comment: @rubylovely You **must** be kidding me. Four votes spread out over *many* hours? Stop bugging me over *nothing*.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - I want to vote on your update too...

Answer (score 16):

While the majority of the downvotes you have received appear to be due to clearly explained technical problems with your answers, your attitude toward other members of this site has led to a more negative reaction than would probably be present otherwise.

For example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124735/letter-count-in-a-sentence-using-ruby), you posted an answer that was very quickly accepted by the asker ([who happens to be a friend of yours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167033/most-recent-bad-behaviours-of-so-users-i-have-faced)), and then proceeded to attack two of the other askers in comments by claiming their answers were plagiarized (in comments that I removed). You presented absolutely no evidence for these claims, yet you flagged one of their answers to be deleted as a result. When I warned you about this in the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16124748/19679) (10k SO users), let's just say you didn't respond as positively as you could have.

There already were downvotes on your answer at that time due to what seemed to be legitimate technical complaints, but these attacks on other established users of the site seemed to have prompted some unfavorable attention to your answer. It didn't help that you attempted to delete that answer and re-post it to clear the downvotes and comments on it.

You frequently go out of your way to criticize competing answers, often going after the same people. Perhaps a more positive approach to dealing with others here would lead to better results.

Comment: Ugh, what a nut. And it's not the first time this discussion's been had with this user

Answer (score 4):

Post good, correct answers.  Heed the feedback in your comments to improve them.  Delete answers that are highly downvoted if they are indeed wrong and you cannot salvage it.  The system is working by design.

Comment: Deleting downvoted answers (especially if done often) might not be advisable. This could play a role in an answer ban. If it happens on a rare occasion, that is just fine.

Comment: nothing wrong,they are working properly, I have pasted the output too.

Comment: @Ruby well, some people seem to disagree, among them very reputable users. I'm not saying that makes them right automatically, but....

Comment: without reason if they keep going to down-vote me, my rep will be `0`. why should I have been dis respect? They are reputable, but they also started from my position.

Comment: @RubyLovely you posted bad answers.  It's that simple.  It didn't answer the question.  It wasted people's time reading it.  The downvotes were not "for no reason" - they were because your answer was bad.  If you continue posting bad answers and your reputation hits 0 (actually 1), it will accurately tell other users to ignore your answers because they're probably wrong or useless, and you should not answer further questions poorly.  The way to solve this is to improve the quality of your answers.  The comments on the downvoted answer explain how.  Follow their advice.

Comment: @djechlin Dammn. understand what I mean to say, I corrected code as per the feedback,still down-votes not withdrawn. They did it intentionally.

Comment: Nobody is obliged to undo the downvotes. Heck, the downvoters might not even be aware of your update to the answer. They won't get notified of that.

Comment: @RubyLovely - people don't monitor every single question they view.  Posting incomplete or substandard answers runs the risk of getting downvoted.  Unless someone is actively monitoring the question, they're not going to know if you made changes or not, hence the downvotes don't get removed.

Comment: @RubyLovely, when you call attention to yourself on meta, you do so at your own peril. FYI. Just file that info away. When you get a downvote, don't complain on meta. You'll simply get more. No, do what everybody else says here. Read and learn from comments and/or other answers. On the offhand chance you actually *were* completely right in your answer, it will all balanceo out anyway.

Comment: @RubyLovely so now it sounds like you're asking, "How to get downvoters to change their votes after I make their requested changes?"  That's a different, legitimate question that I recommend search on meta.SO and possibly posting a new question.

Comment: @djechlin Done many times before and often declined. One such example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c/

Answer (score 3):

If it *is* serial down voting, the system will automatically roll it back within a day or so. Just sit back and wait.

If the mods notice a downvote pattern with some people, they will consider banning the offender for some time - so you're probably safe.

As the other answer says, the best way to avoid downvotes is to write great answers - with code - working code-, formatting and good English - that's how you get rep*.

<sub>*We're all together in the quest to overthrow Skeet.</sub>

Comment: re your footnote; I feel we are not sufficient to the task!

Comment: @AndrewBarber Even if he were put on permanent suspension, it would take years for anyone to catch him since he will always repcap [from passive rep](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/109087/users-that-get-the-most-passive-rep). :)

Comment: @Mysticial *sob* You know how to make a grown man cry, don't you! (and me, too!)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Can mods *take away* reputation?

Comment: @Undo For trivia's sake; No, not directly. Some things that we do will change a user's reputation as a side-effect, but we can not 'adjust' or 'set' any user's reputation.

Comment: @Undo Technically yes, since they can issue binding red-flags. :P But deleting old posts isn't going do anything if they are past 60 days.

Comment: @Mysticial's comment above is not incorrect; It refers to one of the side-effects I mentioned.

Comment: @Mysticial Let's see - assume JS has 150k more rep than any of us. Assuming a mod can cast one spam vote per ten seconds, and spam = -100 rep; then it would take 15,000 seconds to get him under control. My friend Wolfram Alpha says it would take *4 hours* of continuous spam votes to take down JS. Poor mods.

Comment: Ooh; that is devious! Hehe

Answer (score 2):

The answer you provided as exemple is just plain code, without any explanations. You have a few comments explaining why your question is being downvoted.

As for the down-votes in general. Stackoverflow is a community. Your answers won't always please everybody so get ready to accept some downvotes on the way. Programmers don't all share the same opinions on every subjects and sometimes the way you think something should be done might seem unnapropriate or incorrect by another user. Learn to learn from it. There is a comment section to prove you point. I reversed a few downvotes on my previous answers by explaining why I did something in a specific way. You even have flags if you are 100 % sure the comments or downvotes are no justified.

tl;dr : You will get downvoted for all kind of reasons. Deal With it. If not, use the tools provided to you. (comments, flags etc..)

Comment: Glad you mentioned the potential lack of usefulness of code-only answers.