# User Guide for new users to Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, new-users

> As Stack Overflow grows, it becomes increasingly ridden with extremely
>   newbie and mediocre questions. It's just natural. The team are
>   fighting hard to keep the crap out, but there are many very basic
>   questions that are okay on their own. They don't deserve to be kicked
>   out* - they are just very, very, very basic and/or localized.
>
> Too much basicness tires users who are interested in discussing more
>   advanced topics.

However, the new users come from different backgrounds and do not always read the FAQ.

Example: A new user enters the 101 stories high-rise (aka Stack Exchange network sites) with a question. Now the challenge is "Which floor/door do I go to?". The friendly receptionists could point to the small print huge table on the wall, or could have a quick interaction by asking few questions (Entry Exam) to determine and direct.

In order to better facilitate new users I would recommend to have
some sort of **Entry Exam**.

That would tell the user where he/she fits best and what to watch out for.
Further, by providing a user with a badge (Tag), the moderators can constructively help that user navigate through Stack Exchange.

My question is: Is something like an entry exam feasible?

This could involve something like a popup with yes/no questions like:

> What programming language do you use? Java, Python, etc.

Or

> On a Mac, what does the Terminal do?

Comment: Do you have any evidence for your first sentence? Good questions that don't get answered because there are not enough experts and too many newbs who needed to be kept out by an entry exam?

Comment: I think the reputation system works well in this regard. If a user knows what they're talking about, they'll have a higher reputation. With this in place there isn't really a need for an entry exam system, because we can already tell if a user is knowledgeable, and if a user isn't, it's not too hard to leave some constructive criticism and possible downvote their answer if need be.

Comment: The reputation of a user categorically does _not_ mean that they know what they are talking about @davblayn. It means they know how to use the site that they are on. It's easily possible for a new user to be more knowledgeable than the entire current user-base; everyone starts at 1.

Comment: Stack Overﬂow and Stack Exchange face many challenges in the near future. So far,Stack Overﬂow has been successful in serving the programming community. An easy way to increase revenue is to expand user base and ﬁgure out a way to monetize the traﬃc. However, with more than 175,000 registered users as of May 2010 and a history of fast growth, the user growth rate of Stack Overﬂow will ultimately be limited by the population of professional programmers.

Comment: Therefore, the ﬁrst challenge is to determine whether Stack Over-
ﬂow should pursue a larger user base by expanding into domains other than programming, or if the focus should continue to be on software developers. Pursuing other ﬁelds has potential but may require expertise that the core team lacks.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards, the easiest way to gain rep is to give answers to questions that help the asker. While you can earn rep for simple things like edits and, the people with the highest rep have answered more questions about a given topic so that implies that they are more knowledgeable about their chosen topic

Comment: Uh. For non-programming related questions, there're plenty of other Stack Exchange sites available.

Comment: So... you've been a member for 2 days and you already feel familiar enough with the community to make bold claims like "The growth rate of Stack Exchange has exceeded the pool of the experts/programer" and even offer solutions to this (imaginary) problem? I call bs.

Comment: Are you looking to make Stack Overflow only serve seasoned pros? Should it not be a place for beginners and learners?

Comment: You're gonna have to explain how "what programing language do you use (xyz, or none)" is a useful question in determining whether a user fits the site. Your examples aren't representative – in fact the whole request doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I feel quite a lot of oscillation.

Comment: Benalmadena - your questions so far show you seem to be intent on making changes despite your lack of understanding of how SE works. How about hanging around for a  year or so - see if you can't identify things that do need fixing.

Comment: To clarify: the Information comes from this document: http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee204/Publications/Finding%20a%20Growth%20Business%20Model%20at%20Stack%20Overflow.pdf

Comment: There are 101 Stack exchange Inc. sites. How do I find where to ask my question ?...= Entry Exam might help with that.

Comment: It says "However, with more than 175,000 registered users as of May 2010 and a history of fast growth, the user growth rate of Stack Overﬂow will ultimately be limited by the population of professional programmers. Therefore, the ﬁrst challenge is to determine whether Stack Overﬂow should pursue a larger user base by expanding into domains other than programming, or if the focus should continue to be on software developers." in the document you linked to. How exam will help this?

Comment: You are correct, the growth will not stop but the RATE of it will decline.

Comment: @Benalmadena on second reading your post and comments I think you totally miss the whole concept here. Each site on Stack Exchange network is **different**. If you want to ask how to make a yummy sandwich, asking you what programming language you're using is.... pointless. New user can view the [list of sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) and after quick look find http://cooking.stackexchange.com/. Exam for all possible sites is simply not possible.

Comment: Think of what it would do for StackOverflow's revenue.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO exactly my point.

Comment: A guy walks into a French restaurant and before trying anything on the menu begins to explain to the staff and customers that the linguini and enchilada dishes don't use the right kind of herbs for the restaurant to be profitable.  The waiter kindly hands the man a menu.

Comment: @JeffWolski** the same guy arrives in Paris and starts asking a question where is the best place to eat !

Comment: I think @FreshPrinceOfSO was making a *contradictory* point; it would have a negative effect.

Comment: @AndrewBarber why would you say that, do you have any data to support your claim.  I would say it will clearly have a positive effect on the SE In. revenues. Compared to been send to the FAQ, and the T&C pages that no one ever reads, an Interactive form would be fun to use, thus increase users satisfaction resulting in an increase in revenues. Please read the business study for the SE Inc. i published here.

Comment: Some people would abandon the introductory process entirely.

Comment: If you are selectively deleting my comments than this discussion does not make sense anymore, so what is it going to be!

Comment: @Benalmadena Absolutely *none* of your comments to this question were deleted.

Comment: @AndrewBarber there is an update showing there is a sort of Entry Exam already.

Comment: I have absolutely no clue what those pictures you posted mean.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I thought it was obvious, the first one shows current system, burdening the experienced users, the second one shows what an entry exam  for new comers could do. <

Comment: It's not at all obvious. Your description doesn't help, either. Are you saying we *need* one, or we *already have* one? (neither of which is true in the least, in my opinion...)

Answer (score 15):

> Is something like entry exam feasible ?

**No, No, No!**

Did I say No!

The Stack Exchange sites are community drive Q&A sites that are open to **everyone**. There is no requirement that says, you have to pass an entry exam to be able to participate.

I would guess that new users fall into two categories:

1. new to Stack Exchange sites but have knowledge about a particular site topic
2. new to Stack Exchange and new to a site topic

When I joined Stack Overflow, I fell into category 2. I had never used any Stack Exchange site and I knew very little when it came to programming. If I had been given an entry exam I might not have been able to answer any exam entry questions, that is why I was joining Stack Overflow.

People join these sites because they have questions and need answers, or they have experience and knowledge that they can add to the community by answering questions. I have personally learned a lot from using these sites and yes, I had some bad questions and answers when I was learning the ropes.

You also state that the Entry Exam:

> would tell the user where he/she fits best and what to watch out for.

The FAQs and the About pages for each site provide an overview of how each site works including the types of questions to ask, etc.  There is also a Meta Site for each Stack Exchange site as well as the main [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) site if a new user has questions about the Stack Exchange sites.

> Further, by providing a user with a badge (Tag), the moderators can constructively help that user navigate through Stack Exchange.

I am pretty sure the Moderators did not sign up to babysit new users. There is far too much other work for the Mods to handle, especially on some of the larger sites.

You haven't provided enough reasoning behind why you think this is a necessary feature for the Stack Exchange sites and I do not think this a feature that should be implemented.

Comment: Hm, just to clarify, this is a no from you then? ;P

Comment: You got it wrong, the entry test is not to pass or not, it is to direct that users questions to the right place, and alert moderators about the users qualifications in asking the correct way.

Comment: @Yannis Was that not clear enough? :)

Comment: @Benalmadena There is a About/FAQs page for each site that explain what the site it about and what to ask and how to ask.

Comment: I am working on improving my reasoning, so far I just trew in an idea to get some feedback how to make Stack Exchange unique (it already is in some ways), but I do not know of another forums that does something like Users Guide questioning. Stack Exchange is a jungle of 101 sites.

Comment: @Benalmadena There's not much moderators could do with that kind of information.  People's contributions to the site in the form of questions and answers is what we mostly focus on, not the users themselves.

Comment: @Benalmadena, calling Stack Exchange a "forum" shows you don't know the place [well enough](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/185667).

Comment: @bluefeet when you buy a new car do you actually read the manuals or do you drive it first. What I mean to say, you do not think for a moment people spend hours reading the FAQ and the About ect... before posting.

Comment: @Benalmadena Before buying a car I will research it first to make sure it is a good fit for me. Same thing if I were to post on a website, I would make sure it was the right place before posting.

Comment: Just to clarify, the Stack Overflow is no longer the official company name. http://www.usv.com/2011/03/stack-overflow-becomes-stack-exchange.php

Comment: @brasofilo sorry for the typo but in the heat of answering all the flood it happens :)

Comment: **OK, I failed to convey the need for User Guide (test) to help them navigate the Stack Exchange sites.

With (-) 22 votes the majority has decided that it does not make sense having it.**

Thank you all for your active participation.