# How do I find the correct site to post a question? I see no forums listed on homepage?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am new to using this tremendous resource and wish to do it justice by closely following the rules of engagement.

My problem is locating the correct site to post my question. Please see the link containing screenshot. Please advise me on the proper steps to take.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

First step would be to realize that there isn't a single forum on this network. Only Q&A sites. There's a big difference, check the [about](https://superuser.com/about) page on any of the sites. (In particular, there are no support forums.)

As for your question, did you try the obvious (i.e. do what the error message tells you)? If yes, you might have a question for [Super User](https://superuser.com/). If no, go ahead and try out what the error message tells you first.

If you do post on Super User, please post the complete description of your problem in text, inside your post. Images and external links should only support your question, not be the meat  of it. Also make sure you describe what you've tried so far to fix your issue yourself.

You can get an overview of all the sites on the network by visitin the [site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday). When you find a site that looks like it could be a good fit for your question, read it's "about" page, and its FAQ, to make sure you've got it right.

(And no, the list of related questions in the "Ask a question" page only lists questions from the site you're on. It doesn't list questions from other sites.)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. "... there isn't a single forum on this network." Here is how I was led to think that I should first find the correct forum...

"When You Ask

Choose your forum carefully..."
That quote was from here http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#forum "How to Ask Questions the Smart Way"
Thank you for your response and helpful info.
And yes, I have tried the suggestion cited in the error to no avail. Also have posted this very same issue with the Adobe Forum and have gotten over 60 views without a single solution offered. Thanks again!

Comment: The distinction is between traditional internet _forums_ where anything goes and long-winded discussions and debates are common, and _Q&A sites_ where the rules are much more strict (no long discussions or debates, only questions and answers). Please do read the "about" page on the sites on this network. And read the FAQs.

Comment: @DPano, please, refer to this Question about the forum nature of this site (none): [Is Stack Overflow a forum?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/185667). This is [tag:by-design] and helps it being so useful as it is.

Comment: @DPano Note that the FAQ you referred to is not the FAQ for Stack exchange sites and many parts of it are not applicable here.

Comment: Thank you all for correcting my mistake.You should remove this info from your pages and links then; "When You Ask Choose your forum carefully..." That quote was from here catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#forum "How to Ask Questions the Smart Way" Thanks again! –

Comment: @DPano: look at the URL you quote, that's an external resource not a site Stack Exchange controls.

Comment: That is true, nonetheless, the link was found on a stackoverflow page here as a relevant item...http://screencast.com/t/vIDxILkZmk

It was easy to perceive it as a 'How to' page. Therefore, I clicked on that link. Maybe it should never have been placed on the page.

Comment: If you don't take notice of where you're being redirected on the web, you've got more serious issues than Stack Exchange terminology.

Comment: Certainly not, the philosophers and teachers you quote had talent. I didn't even manage to get you to read a single About or FAQ page completely... Until you do that, expect not to understand the network.

Answer (score 2):

Stack *Overflow* is not a site of **forums** organized by topic.  It is a site of questions for programmers by programmers related to the problems they encounter programming.  Posts are not organized into forums per se but rather tagged according to the topics they involve.  See the [About](https://stackoverflow.com/about) page for more information.

Having said this, I think the Stack *Exchange* **site** where you may want to post your question, tagged appropriately for Adobe Acrobat I would expect, is [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Comment: Thank you for the information you just provided me. From now on I will navigate more on the tags. I have yet to become intuitive with the site and all it offers; seems so encyclopedic in scope. Thanks again!
-Dan