# post deletion - Noty (notifier) is not working inside a function

Tags: discussion, specific-question

My post on the question [Noty (notifier) is not working inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977001/noty-notifier-is-not-working-inside-a-function), not sure why. I am kind of new to SO, so it will be great if I know the reason.

Comment: What post-answer or comment? And which question-link it ?

Comment: Do you mean your question was deleted? Or that you could not post it in the first place? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 8):

Your post was not an answer to the question, it was just stating that you have the same problem. See [Is Stack Overflow a forum?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum/92110#92110) for discussions about the differences between our Q&A system and the discussion forums you're used to.