# When is the list of the users who selected a close reason shown?

Tags: support, closed-questions

Looking at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188677/help-me-with-reputation, or [post deletion - Noty (notifier) is not working inside a function](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188547/post-deletion-noty-notifier-is-not-working-inside-a-function), I notice that in one case, the list of user selecting the close reason is shown, but it's not so in the other case.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

Notice that:

- The closure didn't involve any moderator
- In the first case, the close reason is reported to be selected from 5 users (which means all the users who voted to close)

In which cases is the list of users who selected the closing reason shown?

Comment: The first one is the sub-reason for off-topic closure. There could be more than one of them. The second closure doesn't have a sub-reason.

Comment: If that is the case, then another question raises: Why in the first case do I get the list of who selected the sub-reason, while in the second case I don't get the list of who selected that reason? In the second case, two users could have selected a different reason; I will never know who selected the closing reason that appears under the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I understand it, this is a sub-feature of the new Off-Topic close reasons. It only applies to the Off-Topic reasons, which is why it doesn't appear on the "unclear what you're asking" banner.

I believe the criteria for displaying a "the users who voted to close gave this specific reason" message is that at least 2 users voted for the same thing, and there is no sort of tie (ie. 2 users vote for one OT reason and 2 users vote for another). Regardless, when the system chooses a "specific reason" to display, it also tells which users voted to close *with that specific reason*. In the example you're showing, all 5 users agreed and gave the same specific reason, which is why it looks a bit redundant. If, for example, ben and Michael had voted for a different OT reason, their names would appear in the "put on hold as off topic by" list but not in the "gave this specific reason" list.

I hope that made sense and answered your question; let me know if anything else is still confusing!

Comment: I'm not so sure about this bit in the 1st sentence in your 2nd paragraph: "and there is no sort of tie". I recently had exactly this scenario, where there was a tie; the site did display "the users who voted to close gave..". Unfortunately, the question on SO has been deleted, however, I do give some detail about the SO question in this [meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187300/close-vote-reason-logic-when-there-isnt-a-majority)

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I do not understand the "sort of tie" sentence either.

Comment: @chuex I think that in a case where 2 users select a reason, and 2 users select a different reason, the system picks up the last chosen reason, or the first one. I don't remember exactly, but a specific reason is chosen.

Answer (score 2):

This only appears if the final verdict was "off topic". I'm not entirely sure how the close reason is determined (there's some order of precedence iirc), but basically, if a post is closed as "unclear", the *only* message shown is the "unclear" message.

However, if the post is finally closed as off topic, all of the subreasons used are put in a bulleted list, with the break up of who voted for what.

Self plug: [Don't choose the best close reason, allow multiple close reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185983/dont-choose-the-best-close-reason-allow-multiple-close-reasons)