# Great Q&A! Can I have some?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I have to say that I *love* your Q&As and am an active member in five of them. They are so good actually that I would like to ask if I can get involved.

Let me explain a bit. In our secondary school [TŠC Kranj](http://499.gvs.arnes.si/tsc/) we would need a good Q&A for  math, physics, and programming so that our students could contact professors easily in case they had any questions - we are striving to increase the knowledge standards. I would need a Q&A to include a LaTeX based editing "MathJax" (like on Physics Stack Exchange) and a "code" editing tool for programmers. And your sites have it all.

Is it possible to get my hands on the code for this site so I could edit it and reuse it for our school? I saw it is a CC licensed - this is why I am asking. What are my other options? I can ask the principal if he would invest some money in a Q&A like this.

Comment: Love the enthusiasm. Beware the f-word word though (forum), gets peoples blood a-boiling

Comment: Is Q&A more appropriate? :)

Comment: Not just "more appropriate". It's the only correct term. ;)

Comment: [Is stack overflow a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum)

Comment: Thinking that the Q+A at the SE sites is just the software is a mistake.  Tried before with SE1 and that completely didn't work.  It's people, and the way they go about it, that makes it tick.

Comment: @UphillLuge: I agree! If you have no experts. You have no answers to questions, just look at Yahoo Answers.

Comment: Unless your students have to have answers from *only* their professors for some reason, you could always have them ask their questions on the appropriate Stack Exchange site. Like you say, we have sites for math, physics, and programming. Doing your own thing seems cool, but like Uphill Luge says, you'd miss out on all the experts that *really* make this site great.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We don't release our source, but there are a lot of clones out there - [Stack Exchange clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones).

Comment: I like any place that actively promotes their competitors for the benefit of a stranger on the internet

Comment: I thought there was a licensing or hosting option whereby if some company wanted to pay for it, that SE would provide a private SE instance for the firm's use?  I imagine that this is not what @71GA is talking about, though.

Comment: This is what I expected afterall it is your work. Are there any options if you could host this site for our school so that we don't see the source code?

Comment: @Cyberherbalist That did exist, but was a long time ago and is no longer done. The SE 1.0 process worked roughly that way, the SE 2.0 process (see Area 51) does not.

Comment: @Caleb, that's good.  I was worried I had imagined it!  My memory is still working, hooray!  Maybe not every day, but often enough.

Comment: And even if they still did, getting your principal to pay some hosting for a clone is far more likely than coughing up the money for an SE hosted website.

Comment: @Caleb too bad... So will i have to try with some open source Q&A sites?

Comment: @71GA That's likely your best bet.

Answer (score 8):

The site code itself is proprietary, only the user provided content (viz. the things users like you and I write and post here) is CC licensed.

If you have a large enough interest base and a topic that is globally applicable you could propose an official SE site through the [Area 51 site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), however if you want this for a private or local interest group, you will need to handle this on your own. There are [several clones of the SE software platform](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) available, several of them open source.

Comment: "if you want this for a private or local interest group, you will need to handle this on your own" - the page itself should be private for school use yes.