# Where to ask question about logic?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've got a question I want to ask about logic, specifically vacuous truths, but I'm not sure where, if anywhere, on SE it would go. My first choice would be a logic SE site, but I didn't see any in the list.

I'm leaning towards one of the math sites, but I'm not entirely sure if that's the right spot, since it doesn't really feel like a math question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/)** is the correct site for your question. They even have a **[Logic tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic)** there. See their **[Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)** for more details, and perhaps ask in their chat.

Comment: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/.  It's [more about deductive reasoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) than math.

Comment: Ack.  Never mind.  The Wikipedia says it's about math.

Comment: I've done as you suggested. Added a couple of X's and Y's to make it feel a bit more mathy :D

Comment: It would be perfectly on topic for either site, Mathematics or Philosophy. It all depends on how you phrase/present the question. Choose whichever community you like better, @Stephen, or whichever one you think will be most likely to get you the type of answers you desire. Madara has linked to the [logic] tag on Math, but [there is one on Philosophy](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic), too. Also see the "Related Tags" in the sidebar, like [philosophy-of-mathematics] and [modal-logic].

Comment: Is there any reason not to ask in *both* Mathematics and Philosophy? I have a similar type of question which could be applicable to either, and for which I'd like some historical background about thought on the problem, which would seem more suited to Philosophy, and a mathematical proof if possible, which would obviously be suited to Mathematics. I can't think of any harm in posting in both forums, to get the widest discussion (obviously there will be people who are active in both and will see the same question, but I can't think of how that would be a problem to anyone).

Answer (score 5):

The [Philosophy Stack Exchange](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) would also be a good place. [Logic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic) is currently the most popular tag.

Answer (score 1):

Philosophy is regarded by some people as "the mother of all sciences" - I expect you could create a lot of heated discussion on both forums for asking if that is true! - so some would say maths is a branch of philosophy (and maybe some would say the opposite!). Either way, I think either Mathematics or Philosophy would be appropriate - or indeed, both! I have a similar type of question and intended to ask it on both forums (fora?), to get the widest scope of discussion. Unless anyone can think of a good reason not to.

Comment: Please do not mix your answer with a new question. wrt your "question" see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu and also wrt fora: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums