# Too high a cost for a new user

Tags: discussion, new-users

I like Stack Overflow, but being a new user, I:

1. Cannot create tags for new question types
2. Cannot reply with a positive answer to a qeustion, even though I have a working solution
3. Cannot get proper response to question just because of added concept of bounties and blah.
4. Necessity to include at least one tag but what if that one tag is the one not created, but that describes it the best?

I personally think this defeats the entire purpose of an open forum for asking questions!

Comment: Half of your points are about tags; what tags do you need to create? I'd also be interested to understand why bounties _stop_ you getting a response..?

Comment: But this is not an open forum...

Comment: And you **can** reply with a positive answer to a question as a new user. I have yet to ask a question, in all my time on SO, I started with *answers* from day one.

Comment: If you think that the tag(s) that your questions needs don't exist, and you're on SO, there's an approximately 100% chance that the appropriate tags do in fact already exist (this won't always be the case on much smaller sites though).  Either what you think should be tags shouldn't in fact be tags, or you're using a synonym of what the tag really should be.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I assume he's talking about self answering, which has heavier rate limiting for lower rep users, if memory serves.

Comment: I was looking to make my question more relevant by tagging it with something related to knockout.js but no such tag existed nor could I create one.

Also, if this is a relevant question, why is it being downvoted so much?

But, I'll ignore all that and thank you all for your positive responses. I'll get into your suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: @Servy: yes, if you don't post the answer *when posting the question* there is a few hours wait time.

Comment: @Ashish [Oh really](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knockout.js).  You must have mis-spelled it when searching.  It's a good thing you don't have tag creation privileges, if you did you'd have created yet another misspelled tag and wouldn't have gotten the proper visibility for your question.  Or, as mentioned by Bart, you could have been on the wrong site.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm pretty sure that's what he means when he says he can't post an answer, rather than that he can't answer any old question due to rep.

Comment: That tag does exist on Stack Overflow @Ashish. Are you sure you were trying to post there? You weren't trying to post on Meta by any chance?

Comment: @Bart I was posting in programmers or programming. I guess, I'll try stack overflow

Comment: You couldn't find a knockout.js tag on Programmers, because implementation questions (99% of knockout.js questions) are off topic on Programmers. Take a few minutes to familiarize yourself with a site, before you complain it doesn't have the features you are looking for. More often than not, there's a reason the features don't exist.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Cannot create tags for new question types

New question *types*? What do you mean by that? We don't allow metatags so tagging by *type* is not a good idea.

> Necessity to include at least one tag but what if that one tag is the one not created, but that describes it the best?

If you can't find *any* tag to fit your question, chances are that the question is off topic. If there are tags that fit, use them.

> Cannot reply with a positive answer to a qeustion, even though I have a working solution

Why not? There are no reputation restrictions for answering questions, other than the ones which are protected.

> Cannot get proper response to question just because of added concept of bounties and blah.

Very few people use bounties, and most people get their questions answered. You may wish to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for tips on how to improve your question, usually the problem is that the question is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

1,4

Use a more general tag which will help other users identify the context of your situation. It is highly unlikely that you came across something which has never happened to anyone else and is more likely that you are trying to be a little too specific.

Other users will generally help with the correct tag use for new users as well.

2.

Stack Overflow doesn't have a monopoly on experts. If you have a working solution which no one else provided, there is no reason why it will not be positively received. Everyone has to start somewhere and most users understand that reputation is not a measure of knowledge but of contribution.

3.

Most questions do not need to be bountied in order to receive attention. However, questions are expected to follow certain guidelines to make them answerable and topical.

Granted, sometimes there are very hard edge case scenarios that may need a bounty to help them along, but for the most part questions will get enough attention to generate answers. New users get answers to their questions every minute on Stack Overflow.

And last but not least, [Stack Overflow is not a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/178816)

Answer (score 1):

The core functionality of Stack Overflow is two things: *Questions* and *answers*. And you can do both. The rest of those things are icing on the cake, and things that we've decided over time take a little bit of experience for people to really 'get'.

I recommend getting into the site by doing what it's here for. You'll find yourself able to do those things in no time.