# Hyperlink to not-so-relevant Microsoft KB article in SO How to Ask section needs to be removed

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, hyperlinks, help

In the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section of SO, under the heading **Related** on the right sidebar, there is a link to a not-so-relevant Microsoft KB article.

[image]

**Link in question:** [How to ask a question](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555375)

This article does not help users ask a good question on StackOverflow, due to its target audience of general hardware/Microsoft-related software problems, and how to ask questions **on forums**. (May I kindly remind everyone again that [StackOverflow is NOT a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/165483)). Off-topic and/or unnecessary stuff like adding a "thank you" line is encouraged?

Excerpt from article that does not follow SO's "good-question" policy:

> Include a basic description of your system, as relevant to the
>   problem. For example, include the following:
>
> - The operating system version
> - The CPU or processor
> - The video card (also known as a graphics device, video adapter, or GPU)
> - The amount of system memory (RAM)
> - The hard disk size and model
> - The version of software or model of hardware that you’re using and that may be related to the problem
> - The version of virus scanner or malware scanner that you’re using
>
> It may be difficult to determine some of these specifications. The
>   following are examples of free programs that you can use to find this
>   information:
>
> - Speccy - System Information from Piriform
> - Belarc Advisor - Free Personal PC Audit
>
> Include the following information:
>
> - Any software or hardware that you recently installed or removed
> - Any recent changes that were made to the system
> - The amount of time that that you have experienced the problem
> - The things that you have already tried to troubleshoot the problem,    and the results.

**StackOverflow is not a forum!!!**

> Add a thank-you line. This may seem obvious, but it’s easy to
>   overlook, and it’s important to be courteous and polite **in the forums**.

Furthermore, the section "Additional troubleshooting methods", do not apply to StackOverflow.

**I suggest that this misleading article link be removed, so as to especially avoid confusing new users.** (and letting them think they can post their hardware questions here)

Comment: To take a step further, maybe even change the link to something that *is* tailored to Stack Exchange? I'd imagine we *do* want some useful reading information there.

Comment: I must ask... is this a free hand circle? If so you got a very stable hand!

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes and No. Yes, I actually drew this ellipse. No in the sense that I saved it as a template freehand path in Photoshop so that I can reuse the exact same freehand circle in the future (cos it looks so good!). Not the first time however, I previously used it in several other screenshots in meta.

Comment: Oh, so it's a UFHRC!

Comment: @ShadowWizard what's a UFHRC?

Comment: Well, "FHRC" is probably "free hand red circle", but I'm not clear on what "U" is. Maybe "used-to-be"?

Comment: What @Dennis said and the "U" stands for "Used", as you're re-using it. ;)

Comment: Second-hand freehand circle? ;)

Comment: @Mołot That'd be if he had saved someone *else's* FHRC as a template freehand path in Photoshop. :P