# Is there a Zemax community?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am new to Stack Exchange and its constellation of sites. I was wondering if there is a **Zemax** (optical design software) user group here that I could interact with for all things **Optical Design** related?

If not, could anyone redirect me towards a relevant site?

Also I am aware that Radiant Zemax have their own forum (http://forum-en.radiantzemax.com/), which is limited, and apparently a "community" (http://zemax.com/community/zugi) although this seems too formal/professional for me.

Comment: Look at the bottom of the page. Find the "Area51" link. That is where new sites are proposed, refined and come to life. But I doubt you'll find enough interest in so specialized an topic.

Comment: @Anael Bear in mind: this place isn't a forum; it's a Q&A site. If you confuse this for a forum things are going to seem _very_ weird.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. It is a topic too specialized to have its own site. However the Optical Design community should still have a place to discuss on StackExchange. If not in the physics site then where?

I would add that I don't understand why this post was downvoted and moved to meta. It would still be usefull for my peers to view it and see they have a place to ask their questions here, don't you think?

Comment: @Anael Two reasons for that: (a) A physics site is for asking questions about physics. The physics _meta_ is the place for asking about the physics site. (b) Since questions like this actually are more about the _entire network_, you instead got moved to the _entire network's_ meta, rather than just the meta of the physics site.

Comment: No, but I'm sure lots of people are *anxious* to have one!  Get it?  Oh, wait, **Zemax**.  Sorry, never mind.

Comment: The Stack Exchange sites are ***not*** forums (see e.g. <http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115>) (fora?). They are think tanks (ref. <http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681>).

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for the help.

Just to clarify I didn't expect to find a Stack Exchange site specifically dedicated to Q&A about the Zemax software (although I was surprised to find one for Mathematica), but merely trying to find a place to ask my questions and reach the right people.

After a little more research, I see that most software-specific questions are simply posted on Stack Overflow with a specific tag (solidworks, pspice, etc.), so this is simply what I'll do and I am looking forward to be able to create the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Zemax is definitely too narrow, but a computer modelling (for optics, mechanics, electronics, CFD, multiphysics) site is definitely missing. Let's try to close this gap: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/112977/computer-modelling. Feel free to support.

Comment: SO accepts a wide variety of software usage questions.

Answer (score -1):

The [mathematical modeling](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57490/mathematical-modeling) proposal on Area 51 might be the best place for such questions once it is off the ground.  Very specific Zemax questions will probably be duds if not even off topic, but general questions about ray tracing in optical systems or questionable results will fit in.

Comment: Zemax has taken their formerly public forums private, so this is very relevant to a community of over 10k engineers, who use this software. Stackoverflow has plenty of tags for specific software that might affect smaller communities.