# Where can I ask general curious discussion questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a general discussion section for curious questions? Or are we simply left to swallow such curiosity because the results of it may or may not benefit a big crowd?

#### Sample question

There's an idiom, "It costs a moon". As of now NASA hasn't *revealed* if the Moon has precious elements.

This brings some curious thoughts to me...
What if the Moon has precious metals, gas, etc.? Does anyone own the moon or other planets in our solar system? Like Americans? Russians, Germans, Japanese, Chinese or British? Are there any constitutions that refrain anyone from such access or ownership to solar elements (either research wise or commercial wise)?

---

Comment: That sounds like something you should ask your [favorite search engine](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=who+owns+the+moon). I'd say that's probably true for most "gee, I wonder..." queries. Stack Exchange isn't meant to be the repository for all knowledge. (Also, [the answer](http://nasawatch.com/archives/2014/02/who-owns-the-mo.html) is: nobody, by U.N. Treaty.)

Comment: All perfectly answerable by any search engine.

Comment: If you don't want to search and prefer to ask somebody, [Wikipedia's reference desks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk) may fit the bill (for example, the [Science desk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Science) (incl. technology)). Quora also accepts a wider range of questions (sample: *[If we used the resources from the asteroid belt could we create a space station big enough to house 10 million people?](https://www.quora.com/If-we-used-the-resources-from-the-asteroid-belt-could-we-create-a-space-station-big-enough-to-house-10-million-people)*).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does anyone own the moon or other planets in our solar system? Like
>   Americans? Russians, Germans, Japanese, Chinese or English? Are there
>   any constitutions that refrain anyone from such access or ownership to
>   solar elements (either research wise or commercial wise)?

This type of question could possibly be asked on [politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/). Read [this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking a question on there though.

However, this type of question

> What if Moon has precious metals, gas or etc?

probably isn't a good fit anywhere on the network. There is [space.SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but that is for more practical things and not what ifs. I could possibly even see a question being made related to this on [skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but as it stands now, you're question is not a good fit anywhere.

General discussion questions are what forums are for. Stack Exchange sites are not forums.

Comment: I found a new SE site : skeptics.SE. Well let me see, how I could possibly change my question to ask there. However as for the edit on your Question about [*Forums*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum) : it really depends how qualitative, and responsive a forum is.

Comment: It's not about the upvoting. Mainly I was curious. And if I have to ask a technical question, I could manage most probably up to SO standards (so far).

Answer (score 4):

> What if Moon has precious metals, gas or etc?

Questions about the documented and speculated resources of minerals etc. are generally on topic on [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/).

Because it's about resources on the Moon, [Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/) should also be the correct site.

As already stated, question about legal issues are best fit on Politics.SE, because it's where the international specialists are.