# What is the appropriate place to ask for advice on which technology or plugin to use for a specific purpose?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am developing a website in [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) and am looking for the appropriate front-end and back-end plugins to crop, rotate, and resize images. I have enough experience on Stack Overflow to know that such a question is not appropriate for that forum. What would be the appropriate place to ask for help with what plugins and libraries to use on a project?

Comment: [*Stack Overflow* is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115).

Comment: If you are looking for **specific** software, you may be able to ask on [Software Recommendations.SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but before you ask, you should read their [help center](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help) first and pay attention to the [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Comment: Search engines. Find your options, prototype the best candidates, choose what suits you best. That's the only way to be sure. That, and nuking it from orbit.

Comment: Really, Peter? You know what i mean.