# Equation editor

Tags: support, editor, latex

I have been searching on the platform to see if I could get an equation editor to aid questions. unfortunately my efforts were futile.

please can someone show me where I can find an equation editor in the forum?

Comment: For one thing, Stack Exchange is not a forum!

Comment: What do you mean by *equation editor*? Do you want to edit questions with mathematical formula(s)/(e)?

Comment: Some sites on StackExchange support mathjax, but it's on a per-site basis, not across the network (and it's not an 'editor', you still need to type it in the correct format yourself).

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M he probably means something like [this](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php), but embedded in the editor when posting questions or answers on MathJAX enabled sites

Comment: @ Shadow Wizard , thank you, this was what I was looking for.

Comment: [The Stack Exchange sites are not forums](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) (fora?).

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange does not contain such editor, just its own rich text editor.

You can find and use online editors like [this one](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php).

That said, you can turn this very question to feature request asking to add such editor in MathJax enabled sites.