# Notifications set up

Tags: feature-request, notifications, ios-app

I'm new to Stack Overflow and I have a quick question. How do I set up a notification so that I'm informed when a question in the forum gets answered?

Comment: You mean questions that are not yours? No way to get real time notifications for those at the moment

Comment: On a side note: please visit [Is Stack Overflow a forum?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum) (spoiler: it is not).

Comment: Can you clarify if you're looking for answers to your questions or do you want the ability to follow specific questions you see on the site?

Answer (score 1):

If it concerns your own question, you can set up your device to receive notifications of events from the *Settings* > *Notification Center* > *Stack Exchange* menu. You can also view your notifications from the site itself and through email if you have set up your account to receive those.

For questions of other users: you can't and it doesn't see very useful to me to have that in the iOS app specifically, and for the entire site in general. You can favorite a question and you will see updates under the *favorites* tab on your profile page.