# Everytime . . . "How do I join a new site?"

Tags: support, login

I have no idea how to do this. Seriously.

Sometimes SE says "Oh we found your account. Reload to join this site."

Other times it says "Who the hell are you? Register" and then gives the google option... which I didn't use when I registered this account 10 years ago or whenever.

So. . . How do I Join an additional site without creating diverging accounts? *(I've done that before and it was a pain to fix, let alone realize that I'd done it.)*

Comment: [The Stack Exchange sites are not forums](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) (fora?).

Answer (score 1):

Once you have logged in, you should see the *join this community* button on top of the site you are visiting and you don't have an account on yet.

[image]

If you click here, you can create an account on the site without losing association with your current network account.

Comment: I'm aware of that as stated in the question. How do I join that site without creating separated accounts? Since my account wasn't created with OAUTH, and that's the only option to login with, I fear that it will happen again.

Comment: You don't have to login on that form, do you? @monsto Can you show how that looks like on your end?

Answer (score 0):

Each site in the Stack Exchange network of sites is different, and has its own users base.

On each site, you have your own separate profile and account.

When using the same credentials to log in (aka same OpenID) all accounts using those credentials are automatically associated.

Until recently, there was just a "login" option, no "join this community", and you had to manually choose "Google" and type your username and password, confirm the account, and then it was automatically associated.

The "join this community" appears when the site identifies you are logged in into other SE site, then clicking it is just a shortcut that automatically takes your credentials from the other SE site you're logged into, and only asks you to confirm the new account on the site, which will be associated.