# Considerate collective name for stackexchange sites

Tags: discussion, etiquette

[Apparently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum) there is a strong belief that StackOverflow is not a forum.
I don't buy that sort of things but some individuals are very sensitive about this.

What is an accurate and civil one-word substitute for a forum?

Bad examples:

- site - too broad, applicable to both concrete forum and platform in general;
- Q&A site - not *one* word, doesn't matter how short abbreviation is.

---

Using definition instead of a word creates unjustified cognitive load in a context where nobody cares about marketing strategies of Stack Exchange, Inc.

Comment: Why on earth do you have to have only one word to describe something? Q&A site is perfectly fine.

Comment: Community. It has members who also moderate it, it's not just any web site. But technically, it's a Q&A site. If you want a language where everything can be described withoneword, you will probably have to createyourownlanguage.

Comment: @RobertLongson, why use four instead of one? I think this is too pretentious.

Comment: What about just Q &A? Sometimes the word "site" is omitted 'cause it's obvious.

Comment: It's not self-contained nor obvious to new users. Consider it used in a sentence: "This question is off-topic on (in/at/?) this Q&A".

Comment: They will learn pretty quick as I have noticed myself.

Comment: @User I'd choose "site" in that sentence of yours.

Comment: *Site* doesn't differentiate SE platform from a single forum. For example, saying the same thing (with "site") on `x.stackexchange.com` implies `stackexchange.com`, while the question may be perfectly valid on `y.stackexchange.com`.

Answer (score 11):

*Q&A sites* cover the purpose of the sites exactly. If that isn't short enough to you, that is no reason to not call it this way. All sites together are often called the *SE network of sites*.