# What is this question about (english language forum)

Tags: discussion, languages, communication

I would like to ask the meta forum about the logic in this question:

> I once read about a nice word that describes the specific noise made
> by a helicopter in flight.
>
> - It wasn't a generic verb like "rattling" or "juddering", but one that only applies to helicopters.
> - It may have been onomatopoeic, but I'm not sure.
> - I'm almost sure it was a verb (as in "the [...]ing noise of the helicopter"), but it could have been a noun (as in "we could hear the
>   helicopter's [...] from a mile off").
>
> I've hunted on the internet to try to find this word again, but to no
> avail. I'm sure I'll know it when I see it though. Does anyone else
> know this word?

The [link to the question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/319884/word-for-the-noise-made-by-a-helicopter).

1. Is the question about finding the **best word** for describing the sound, or
2. Is the user asking for **a word** that he/she **once saw**?

Being a computer programmer, to me the obvious answer is 2, which renders it hard to answer the question (should have the Q authors head handy, plus a set of good tools for brain scrutinizing). But i must have been wrong, as my hugely simple answer was moderated by user [Sven Yargs](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/36232/sven-yargs) and after my comment efficiently deleted by user [Matt E. Эллен](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/3559/matt-e-%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD).

Given the tremendous reputation of the answering forum members (and these two have 22,203 and 62,577, btw) compared to my tiny one (11, and that I almost got by mistake), plus the fact that english is only my 3rd language, and also considering my young age (I am only 53), well, I almost knew it all in advance! No chances.

But whaddahell, i thought! And Skype founder Niklas Z. told use to be brave! So i did a Google search, for:

helicopter rotors speed of sound +noise

(Good phrase, yes?) And voilá - first hit contains "clapping" - that must be it, I thought! In with it!

But my effort was wiped out. People have replied to the original question with long explanations of why various wording is especially appropriate for helicopter sound, and upvoted those. How does the "appropriateness" relate to the question? Seen is seen, read is read. Should I have described the abovementioned technique for finding the word in my answer? Yet, it seems like a lottery. Is it the word he once read in a book, or is it not? Given my bad luck in everything related to lottery, it's probably not :-(.

Yet, Stack Exchange has a rule set, and for the last 22 hours, my life has been falling apart.

Anyone willing to tell me what is going on? Would it be about communication problems between language and computer science?

(Not having a huge importance here, this matter does in fact have a wider perspective. We often see intentional or unintentional misinterpretions of logic in daily life, and i often feel inconventient when there is an apparent error, **especially** when people swallow it - usually at the topmost, first row).

Comment: Why aren't you asking this at [English Language & Usage Meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Because it is not about the english language itself, rather about the what the substance of the original question is. Could have been any language.

Comment: Also note that [Stack Exchange is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum).

Comment: No Stormwind; what @AlE. meant is that you usually ask about stuff that happens in one site in *that site's* meta. Meta.SE is for issues concerning most or all of the Stack Exchange network. I don't think the whole SE network is concerned over why an answer that contained "Nobody proposed clapping ???!?!? :-)" is deleted.

Comment: Sounds valid. I was unaware of that each site has a meta. It is not obvious. Visiting for example gamedev.stackexchange.com and CTRL-Fing "meta" gives exactly one hit: To this very place, where i write now. The only way to access meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com seems to be typing meta in the address bar? (Though i am sure there is a good pointer somewhere). Perhaps this could be improved? Re. my original question: It is not interesting and the time windows has passed it. I will delete it soon, if possible.

Comment: An answer is not saying "Nobody proposed clapping ???!?!? :-)" How does that help the OP who is asking the question? Where is the support, the backup, the definitions, the citations which makes a lazy, sarky-sounding comment into a proper answer? You can't be bothered to write a full proper answer, then don't sulk or put on a hissy-fit,  if users suspect you're a troll, or someone just passing by and delete your contribution.

Comment: Take a good look at the other answers posted. Do any of them look like one line comments?

Comment: Dear guys, logic gone? He asks for a word "that he once read" and that he "knows when he sees it". How on earth can you, and why on earth should you, possibly make the answer more "accurate" by going into meanings of words? It either is, or it is not, the one proposed to him, REGARDLESS OF HOW FIT, POPULAR OR WELL EXPLAINED THE WORD IS. If i ask "i once had a game, anyone knows which one?" at the coders site, do you seriously think that people should explain why game A is good, why game B is bad, etc...? :-) No, and my question would be depreciated immediately.

Answer (score 7):

The totality of your answer is:

> Nobody proposed clapping ???!?!? :-)

That:

1. Should have beena comment.
2. Isn't  answering the question.
3. Is asking another question.
4. Can't be taken seriously.

Comment: Why wasn't "clapping" [sound] a word as good as any of the other words proposed? I see multiple occurances of "the clapping sound of a helicopter" in the internet. The QUESTION (the only place with a question mark) is: "Does anyone else know this word?" To that, an answer can imho be only Yes or No, correct? You are right in that it could have been a comment, but SE allows low-reputationsers to answer before commenting. I still think there is a severe lack of logic here.

Comment: @Stormwind - you are active on a number of our sites. We expect answers to be more than one sentence, and to be corroborated, usually. As others have noted - your question belongs on the elu meta, not here.

Comment: Ah, my apologies for that - i was totally unaware of "all meta". If you look at my other anwers, you will find them to be very long and carefully phraesd.