# Anything I should know about Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, new-users

I know I'm going to get slammed for the broadness of this question, but I just wanted to ask, is there anything I should know about Stack Exchange?

Basically, what I'm asking is; all forum or community sites have different norms and community-made guidelines that can often make new users feel quite pressured and anxious if they don't follow them, for example, Reddit is rather casual, and stopping or preventing fights doesn't really seem to be a rule that's enforced much. But I've noticed that this site in particular tends to treat users rather harshly if you don't act appropriately, if I'm to be completely honest. So I wanted to ask, is there anything I should know about the overall environment and attitude here, that wouldn't be mentioned in the rules or guidelines, and if you want a more specific question, I have a few:

- How formal/casual should I act?
- What would you consider derailing off of the topic?
- Is it normal to say 'thank you'?
- Can you get instantly banned? Or will you get a warning, telling you not to perform that action again?
- Are there any inside jokes or terms specific to Stack Exchange I should know?

Lastly, I know it's broad, so I don't mind not having an answer, but I'd appreciate if anyone would be able to answer the the original question, which was 'Is there anything I should know about Stack Exchange'?

Comment: Things you should know are covered in [the tour](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help centre](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help) both available from the help menu button at the top of the page.

Comment: that's too broad really though isn't it?

Comment: The questions you've asked might be OK individually, however most if not all of them have been asked and answered here already. You need to spend some time on research first.

Comment: The last one in your set would be covered [by this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta) for instance.

Comment: Read the existing questions/answers to get a feel for that.

Comment: @DavidReichert In general, some SE sites (Stackoverflow, the trilogy sites) are pretty formal. Less so on their meta's. But still pretty formal. You trying to learn about it beforehand already sets you apart from most users there, though. So I don't think you'll have many problems.

Comment: [The Stack Exchange sites are ***not*** forums](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) (fora?). They are [think tanks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681).

Comment: The one thing you must know is that we hate fun.  There is absolutely no fun here.  But the waffles are good.

Comment: Yes: don't ask broad questions or they'll get shut down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How formal/casual should I act?

It really depends on the community and on the setting. In chat, things are very casual in most cases. MSE is also quite casual if you read the comments sometimes. In all other cases, keep your Q/A on-topic, don't put anything in it we don't have to know to answer the question (*I live in England and I just started chemistry. I have a nice cat. Now I have a question about travelling...*) Be professional. Show you have done effort to get the answer yourself. Show your research or attempt to solve the issue. [Be nice!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)

> Is it normal to say 'thank you'?

Yes, but not the way you are used to. We usually thank users contributing by voting. Commenting *Thank you* is considered too chatty on most site. (Consider what happens if every user that votes also places a *thank you* comment)

> Can you get instantly banned? Or will you get a warning, telling you not to perform that action again?

You can get suspended if you are misbehaving. You won't get post banned immediately. The system will warn you first. Also, there is a way to recover from it.

> Are there any inside jokes or terms specific to Stack Exchange I should know?

Lots of them. They have even made an entire Q/A set of it: [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478/245360).