# Why doesn't editing my Stack Exchange profile show up on "all activity"?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, profile-page

Editing answers shows up on "revisions".

However, when I edit my profile on, say, Mathematics Stack Exchange (MSE) and then update my profile in all other accounts in the Stack Exchange network, this update does **not** show up either on my MSE profile or on my Stack Exchange network profile. Is there a reason why this is so?

It would be nice to have all edits pertaining to one's profile showing up on "all activity", so one knows if a bad guy happens to tamper with one's profile.

Comment: "bad guy happens to tamper with one's profile" - not really possible, users can't edit the profile of other users.

Comment: See the comments under my answer. OP is worried about a hijacked account. @Sha

Comment: The purpose of "All Activity" is to draw your attention to items which may interest you or need your attention (answers to your questions, reputation changes etc). You know when you change you own profile, so it doesn't need to be brought to your attention. "All Activity" is not intended as a security measure, and it wouldn't make a very good one for reasons explained by others here.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo What is Quora's "log"? Notifications seems to be Quora's equivalent of SE's inbox, and I didn't get any item in my notifications about a comment I deleted. I know you're not talking about the sub-sub-sub view that is "Edits".

Answer (score 6):

The user profile is not part of the Q/A and doesn't come with revisions and history visible for users. It doesn't make much sense to register changes to one's profile in the revision history.

> if a bad guy happens to tamper with one's profile

You can't change the profile of someone else, unless you are an employee or moderator. That means only you can edit your profile, which makes you the only bad guy. No need to log that in the revision history either.

Comment: How does that help anything?

Comment: Registering a profile change in your revision history. If your account was compromised, you have to contact the team to have that investigated (from the SE abuse side of the story). There is nothing in the revision history what  would help you.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Thanks. Updated.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo As far as I'm aware, that scenario has occurred a grand total of zero times on SE. Even if it has, it's so rare that it's really not worth building in revision history for.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo This isn't security. This is overthinking things. There's always a cost/benefit analysis to do, and in this case, the cost of implementing this is *way* greater than the benefit from it. (Also: those freelancers and consultants better not be using posts to advertise themselves - that's called spam, and it gets accounts destroyed).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo (SE is not a forum, but) 1. To help people. 2. To help people; to build a repository of knowledge. 3. You can't possibly say it's "a few lines only"; you're not an SE dev. Don't make assumptions like that unless you are sure of them.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo [Is Stack Overflow a forum?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/245360)

Comment: How would you know - Your account is linked to your Google account, Google would notify you of the strange activity, if they don't that's on them.  SE just accepts your authencated Google account.  People don't make 50 SE accounts.  Let's stick to non-hypotheticals

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo if someone is so worried about bad guys changing his/her profile, he/she should just ask to delete their accounts upon stopping to use SE. Otherwise, well, nothing much we can, or should, be doing. Adding a complicated profile revision mechanism just for the sake of those rare edge cases isn't a good idea in my opinion, the resources are better spent on other requests and bug fixing.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo that's really not the responsibility of Stack Exchange. And if someone notice something suspicious (e.g. respected user suddenly having "bad" profile info), it's as easy as contacting the team to "fix" that.

Comment: `If profile edits were on "all activity", it would be easier to detect such tampering` how, exactly? Personally, I've looked at my activity history maybe ten times in seven years. If it's about third parties looking at other folks' activity histories - once you have clicked through to see those, *you've already seen the profile*.

Comment: @Rodrigo my main point is that by the time you have clicked through to your activity log, chances are *you have already seen your profile*.