# How do I ask questions on Stack Exchange sites and don't get downvoted?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes

I can get why I am getting downvotes when I ask question about **JavaScript** - I don't have experience and should learn language instead of doing stuff with it.

I can't get why I am getting upvotes on some not-so-popular exchange sites like **neo4j** for a similar stupid question. But it lets me not get banned from the **Stack Overflow** site and keep asking questions.

And I certainly can't get why I am getting downvotes on an iPhone forum when I asked about similarity between a battery in an **iPhone** and a **Tesla** car.

I am not going to give links to my question, because I kind of feel I will get even more downvotes and will get banned. The only thing I want to know - how to not get downvotes?

Comment: are you kidding me?

Comment: Don't worry about the downvotes here. They just express disagreement on metas and are usually handed casually along with upvotes.

Comment: Thank you M.A.R.. If it wasn't me it would be funny how this get's thumbsdowns.

Comment: Without seeing your posts its hard to tell but are you aware of how to structure a good question?  This is from one site but most of it is applicable more generally: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115

Comment: Pavel we don't regard them as ''thumbdowns'' but as 'downvotes'. The main difference here is a thumbsdown/-up is considered to be aimed at the person, while our votes are for the content. The people that downvoted this didn't deem the post useful, just like the person who upvoted it did. It has no relevance to whether they like you or not.

Comment: M.A.R. i would be totally agree with it if absence of reputation points would not ban me from asking questions..

Comment: Pavel, please capitalise "I", both in comments, questions and answers. In English, the subjective form of the singular first-person pronoun, "I", is capitalized, along with all its contractions such as I'll and I'm.

Comment: Damn, I never thought this could be annoying. Thank you and I am sorry.

Comment: Not trying to ask smart questions..

Answer (score 4):

Okay, judging by what you wrote here, I can give you some hints:

1. Make sure to use correct spelling and preferably correct punctuation. A typo doesn't necessarily mean you will get a downvote but as they get more your question is more likely not to be deemed as high-quality and get a downvote.
2. SO's standards should ideally be different from forums. See, [SO isn't even considered a forum.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum) You should use SO as a last resort, where you've tried all you could but still couldn't solve the problem.
3. **Always try, and always include what you tried.** This is perhaps the most important point. SO is currently being flooded by a mass of poorly researched questions. Everyone helping you on SO will be doing it voluntarily, and no one owes you an answer, so you at least need to show that you want to learn.
4. Make sure you understand the SE philosophy. SE/SO is never meant to answer every question that you have. "What is the best iPhone of history?" is not a question that can be answered here, as seemingly your question on Apple.SE.

   The difference/similarities between an iPhone and Tesla battery seems like a question sparked out of your curiosity, but one you didn't try to look for an answer yourself. That is usually an indication that it won't be received well on SE sites. It's a fun question to *discuss* in a chatroom or a forum or whatever, but not that appropriate in an environment that wants to look as professional as possible.

Comment: If i am comming on SE with a solution to a problem and asking to an improvment, it's ok. If i am asking for a solution it is not?

Comment: If I understand your question, no, that's not what I meant. I meant that on SE you should show what you tried to get to an answer, but you couldn't. If you do have an answer, it's recommended that you answer the question yourself if you're sure it's right. For instance, you should say ''I searched iPhone vs. Tesla battery on Google but the [this link] in the results didn't answer my question because . . . ''

Comment: If i show how hard i tried to get this answer it will be appreciated?

Comment: Yes @Pavel, providing that the question is fit for the site. You can't get answers and ''appreciation'' for ''How can I brush my teeth effectively?'' on an Apple site. :) You should also make sure your question's answer relies on facts, not opinions (''Who's the best football player in the world?"), and the answer is not too long (say, more than 15 paragraphs) Even though I've seen questions get answers that long because they sparked the interest of the experts on the subject and they did that with showing research.