# Why am I starting to see Stacks forum style on other websites?

Tags: support, clone

Is it possible to find out if a certain website running a similar forum style to Stack is actually a clone or a new work?  Not trying to give any credit to this site but if you visit  forum(dot)techtudo(dot)com(dot)br/ you will see the same style.

I've read all the clones threads on Stack and know about the list of possible clones but I checked out those websites in that list but none are similar to these others. IS there a way that Stack can detect their code on other platforms?

Example:
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Cause it works pretty darned well, and there's clones? ;p

Comment: Do we have a a free version of it that is similar to Stack available on the web?

Comment: @Hugo Nope there isn't

Comment: [The Stack Exchange sites are ***not*** forums](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) (fora?). They are [think tanks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any other idea that has become massive/successful/ubiquitous, people will copy it.

This is how the Internet works.

Stack Exchange is the number one Q&A site, reaching dominance over many other offerings. If you were to create a site would you try and come up with a new one* or would you copy something you know to work already?

*of course if you do have a brilliant new idea, sure, you'd go with that and hope it would win over the incumbents. After all, that's what SE did.

Comment: Thanks Rory for the response! Perfect sense yeah. it's just so crazy because it looked so similar in some aspects that we start to wonder if it's being distributed. Thanks again!