# Modal for images in Stack Exchange community?

Tags: feature-request, design, images

I've noticed that these forums do lack a LightBox for the images posted by users.

When I click an image in a question to view the full size, it will simply open the image in the parent window, resulting in loss of any answer or comment already written by me. (Yes, there is a autosave for drafts.)

Shouldn't there be a modal or something to view the images in a more friendly way? Is it possible that there is a modal but my browser can't display it? I tried different browsers, but the same effect.

Comment: I’d rather they have images open in a blank window than some off-the-rack lightbox plugin. However, some overlay or opening images in `_blank` would be nice, so I wonder why this isn't the way it is.

Comment: [The Stack Exchange sites are ***not*** forums](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) (fora?). They are [think tanks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681).

Comment: @dakab yes, that would be nice too.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yea i wanted to edit the question but i lost connection. sorry.

Comment: Well then no one cares, since it's not added after 4 years.