# Potential privacy breach due to question rate limit from IP addresses

Tags: discussion, rate-limiting, privacy

I initially asked this question [here](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/824/potential-privacy-breach-due-to-question-rate-limit-from-ip-addresses), in [Bitcoin Meta](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com) because I faced this problem originally in Bitcoin SE. I decided to ask this question here due to the very little attention it received there and it is actually a larger problem to be addressed across SE community and not just Bitcoin. Here is the problem.

> You can only post once every 40 minutes.

I got this response from Bitcoin SE while trying to ask a question, strangely I had not asked anything in last 40 minutes, In fact, that was my first question in the forum. I assumed someone from my IP, Perhaps my office might have asked a question in the same period. As I checked the newest questions in the forum there had been only one question for 40 minutes, It was by a user who has not revealed his identity. But now I have a clue about his IP and I went through the questions from his other SO profiles. Apparently, he is from my office. I did not try further to establish this fact. However, is this not a privacy breach?

Comment: [The Stack Exchange sites are ***not*** forums](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) (fora?). They are [think tanks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681).

Comment: How is it a privacy breach?

Comment: I don't think there's a rate limit past certain rep amount, since I had posted 2 questions on [literature.se] 2 days ago some 10 minutes apart from each other.

Comment: @rene I think he is saying that he knows that this other poster is from his office, because he was the only poster 40 minutes ago. Therefore his identity is not secret. However, I don't think this is a massive concern, as it can only be used to identify users using the same IP as yourself.

Comment: @Gloin that is all true. The OP used some CSI techniques to identify a colleague. He could have used the same techniques WITHOUT knowing they were on the same network and still identify that user. Running into the IP ban only offered extra evidence. Using the words 
 *privacy breach* by the OP suggests that the identity is leaked which is IMO not true, there is extra circumstantial evidence that can be used to narrow down on the true identity. And if it is a breach, it is still only relevant/exploitable in the context of the OP.

Answer (score 4):

> You can post only in 40 minutes in the network sites in which you have a low rep.

If from anyone in your office with low rep, asked a question in **any network site**, that should be the reason.

It is a network wide limit for low rep users.

Comment: OP already knows this and the question is whether that is a privacy issue or not I think?

Comment: @Cai I think he didn't _As I checked the newest questions in the forum there had been only one question for 40 minutes_

Comment: Fair enough, maybe they didn't know it was network wide, but still I'm pretty sure the question is about privacy, not the implementation of the limit

Comment: @SagarV That was my intuition too, but do you have a source for it being a network wide limit?