# Code open-ended, opinionated, code discussions are discouraged on the regular SO. Is there a SO community for that?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Code open-ended, opinionated, code discussions are discouraged on the regular SO.  Is there a SO community for that?

Comment: What's an example of one of the "open-ended, opinionated, code discussions" you wish to have?

Comment: Something like "what's your opinion on this code pattern?"

Comment: StackOverflow seems to be very strict about the questions being specific.

Comment: code review you seek?

Comment: Not code review

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Discussions don't work that well on a QA format. Consider the lack of threadedness of any sort - and how your only tool to follow up an an answer are comments (which rather suck for it. You can't even post more code!). Posting an answer as a reply to an answer is a no no, and the posts semi randomly switch order. People even expect there to be one correct answer much of the time. [Real Questions Have Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/) - and what you're talking about is the very definition of a chatty open ended question (which I'd add, is explicitly in the close reason list.)

It's almost like SE was designed [*explicitly* not to be a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110/135565).

The QA model, as SE does it is designed to minimise noise - and arguably, openended discussion without an end goal is *noise*.

So - there's no community for the specific thing you want. If you could rescope the question, there might be places where it fits, but the specificity is by design. You wouldn't find it as useful otherwise.

Comment: Thank you. I will look outside of stack overflow for this.