# Why does one lose reputation for posting a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, reputation, duplicate-questions

I don't believe it is harmful to have the same questions written in different ways. Many times I search for a question but can't find it, only later to have someone share a question that is phrased very differently. In the end, I have to delete the question so as not to lose reputation.

I am of the opinion that marking a question as a duplicate should not automatically cost reputation.

Comment: Any correction of the question redaction is accepted.

Comment: I recommend never referring to Stack Exchange sites as forums: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115/215590

Comment: Already answered in the FAQ [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) (section *Is there a penalty for asking a duplicate question?*)

Comment: +1 from me, in principle I fully agree that duplicate questions should not be downvoted, however, if the question has been asked a thousand times before and/or finding the answer is relatively easy–e.g. FAQs type of questions–downvoting is a legitimate sign of "disapproval" and "exasperation".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't lose reputation for having a duplicate question. You lose reputation because downvotes cost you reputation. You are (likely) getting downvotes for two reasons:

- The content of your questions appears that you didn't try to find the answer yourself (That is somewhat of an expectation on this site)
- Your use of imperfect English. No matter how hard we try to avoid reacting negatively to poorly stated questions, it is harder to receive questions that are difficult to read.

I also suspect your poor English makes searching for answers that others would deem easy to find significantly more difficult.

Comment: It is very possible that it is the imperfect english. I will try to speak english better. Thank you

Comment: @Elborito You should really stop worrying about your English. Nobody expects it to be flawless (lots of people here have English as a second language/don't live in primarily English-speaking places), and if your English is consistently like what it was in this question and the above comment, there's no way people will downvote for that reason. It's quite clear what you're trying to say in all those communications, and the flaws are extremely mild/superfluous.