# Where can I ask questions about vehicle registration, transfer, etc.?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

This question is more for the vehicle owners, who are possibly moving from one state to another or to a different country.

Several other relevant questions regarding the care, maintenance of the vehicle may also be asked. I'm wondering which forum is appropriate for that? Does such a site exist in Stack Exchange?

Comment: You say [forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums) but I assume you mean a Q/A site within the Stack Exchange Network?

Comment: @rene well, we can assume, and if OP didn't mean it they can roll back and we'll close and delete the question as off topic.

Comment: Even if [the CEO described it as such](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPbbt7Dg-2U&t=2m57) (at 02 min 57 secs), [Stack Exchange sites are *not* forums](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) (fora?). What made you assume there were forums (not a rhetorical question)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding *vehicle registration* might be asked on

https://law.stackexchange.com (I think)

Related tags

- [vehicle](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle) (150 questions)
- [vehicle-registration](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle-registration) (only three questions one of them with a high score)

Regarding *vehicle transfer* from one state to another, they have tags for countries and some USA states:

Relate tags:

- [united-states](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states)
- [california](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/california)

Some related open questions on that site

- [Is it legal to go take my license plates off a car I sold, without realizing I should keep my plates?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/61748/36207) score 31
- [Driving licence and vehicle registration in EU without adress](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/55711/36207)

The previous answers already recommended [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing the OP over to LawSE. For info, the questions, and answers, about vehicle (re)registration are [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/67426/what-are-the-rules-of-transferring-the-registration-of-a-vehicle-from-one-state/67435#67435) and [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/67428/how-to-do-a-vehicle-re-registration-interstate-transfer-in-india/67452#67452)

Answer (score 8):

We have a dedicated Stack Exchange site for Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. [Their Help Center](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) explains what's on-topic there:

> Motor Vehicles Stack Exchange is for mechanics and DIY-enthusiast owners of cars, trucks, and motorcycles.
>
> Questions related to the maintenance and repair of motor vehicles and their accessories, internal combustion engines, even in applications other than automotive so long as the question is related to engine or engine accessories.

Vehicle registration and other legal topics aren't mentioned, but they do have a [couple of questions in the [registration] tag](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/registration). If it's about moving to another country, [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle-registration) might be the right place:

> Expatriates Stack Exchange is for people living or intend to live abroad on a long-term basis, and for questions surrounding ordinary life, just complicated by your status as an expatriate.

Answer (score 6):

There is a site in the network that centres around motor vehicle repairs: [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/)

According to their [help centre](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help) article questions regarding repair and maintenance of motor vehicles is the only thing on topic. <strike>I did a search on their site, but did not find any questions regarding registration of vehicles.</strike>  This is not true, a [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367042/search-on-meta-is-slow-sometimes) caused 0 results, but there are actually comparable questions, like [this one](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/4935/register-car-in-illinois-and-get-plates). That question is closed as off-topic, so it might be a good indicator that it isn't the right site for this type of questions.

> Motor Vehicles Stack Exchange is for mechanics and DIY-enthusiast owners of cars, trucks, and motorcycles.
>
> Questions related to the maintenance and repair of motor vehicles and their accessories, internal combustion engines, even in applications other than automotive so long as the question is related to engine or engine accessories.

If your question on registration is regarding which laws there are to follow, your question might be on-topic at [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/), but be sure to check their [help centre](https://law.stackexchange.com/help) first. When in doubt you could ask on their meta site, if your proposed question would be on topic.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the OP over to LawSE. For info, the questions, and answers, about vehicle (re)registration are [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/67426/what-are-the-rules-of-transferring-the-registration-of-a-vehicle-from-one-state/67435#67435) and [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/67428/how-to-do-a-vehicle-re-registration-interstate-transfer-in-india/67452#67452)