# Search on Meta is slow (sometimes)

Tags: support, status-completed, search, meta

During the last hour or so, searching on Meta Stack Exchange can be very slow; searching only on a tag still works as normal, probably because it automatically redirects to e.g.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion which is not a search page. Sometimes it doesn't even give results:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I noticed but thought it was me. I have the impression search won't start and you need to click search again to get results.

Comment: I also noticed on other sites, when writing [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367036/361484). I thought there were no post with registration(s), but there are about 80 now that the search works.

Comment: The same happened on SO around 9:00 UTC.

Comment: Even help center search [is borked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFZio.png) right now: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=close

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We had some problems during a patching cycle earlier today which affected our tag engine (serving `/tagged` pages). We gave the affected servers a swift kick in the right place earlier today and they're back serving requests again. Apologies for the inconvenience!

Comment: Now I'm curious, what's the right place? ;-)