# Searching on Help Center doesn't return anything network-wide

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, help-center

Searching on [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help) doesn't return anything, even for keywords that I've been often using before:

- ["promotion"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=promotion) (for questionable [spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/promotion))
- ["reference"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=reference) (for [referencing other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing))
- ["accidentally"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=accidentally) (for [duplicate accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)).
- ["accepted"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=accepted) (for [Q/A ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans), or [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer))

All of them returning this screen instead:

[image]

Tried on Meta Stack Exchange, [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=accepted), and [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=accepted).

Comment: Probably related: [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367042/search-on-meta-is-slow-sometimes#comment1223047_367042) under my question from earlier today.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We had a little Elastic blip earlier that appears to have affected the help centre search indexes. I've forced a rebuild and things have come back to life. Apologies for the inconvenience!

Comment: It looks like this has popped back up in the mean time; help page search seems to be failing across the board again.

Comment: Eurgh, yeh same search node ate it and trashed a bunch of indexes, I'm rebuilding them now. Apologies @zcoop98

Comment: @DeanWard There is a similar issue in Ask Ubuntu help center: https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19648

Comment: @randomperson thanks, have pinged our SRE team to dig in