# How to encourage 'real' responses from review, rather than rubber-stamp comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, review, vote-to-close

We've now all seen the message

> Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

far more times than it truly deserves. Personally I'm sick of flagging these as "no longer needed", which is the only option you get on them.

I've now flagged so many of these it's long ceased to be even vaguely amusing. There is no comeback to people who use this flag. It adds nothing but noise, because if the OP truly doesn't know what further information to add, this will not give them any clues whatsoever.

---

*This seems to have been a contentious point,
judging by downvotes and comments, but my point still stands.* 
I have occasionally posted underneath *"Just because you don't understand the question is no reason to flag it as 'needs detail'"*, but, of course, the users who set these flags will get no notification, nor do we have any method to check whether they would ever look back on posts they have flagged to see what eventually happened to them.

---

The counter-argument that it's "too much effort" is why I'm asking this in the first place. How can we make it not 'too much effort' to actually supply a comment that might actually be *useful* to the OP.

---

Perhaps people are posting them in the mistaken belief  that they are 'helping', but mainly they are posted on questions which are **perfectly understandable**, even if they don't flat-out state a clear, unambiguous 'question to be answered'.

That would therefore suggest that they are mainly used by less-experienced users, and we ought to perhaps be looking towards lessening that propensity.

After the revelation in comments that this doesn't appear to be reputation-based, then how do we prevent this capricious rubber stamping?

Comments would also seem to suggest that I need to present a working model of a method to 'fix' this issue. I have no such model, hence the 'discussion' tag. So far, all I've met is pushback.

> Again, not understanding something is a good reason to say it's unclear.

No, it is not. It is a reason to skip the review to someone who **does** understand the question. 
If you don't understand a question, it is equally fair to say that you don't understand the subject matter of the question, so will completely fail to understand what the OP might need. 
Personally I flag most [though not all] of these comments on macOS questions, where it's perfectly obvious to me what they're asking and quite often I have an answer for them and don't even need to edit the question for clarity.

---

The straw that broke the camel's back and prompted me to post this Meta was *[OneTab data recovery from old boot drive](https://superuser.com/questions/1694735/onetab-problems-external-hard-drive)*. 
Sure, it's a terribly-worded question, but its intent is quite clear and needs no clarification whatsoever. It just needs a tidy-up for grammar and syntax, which has since been done. A dupe was easily researched on Super User itself. At present it contains my own close-vote as dupe and one canned comment (flagged by me) with no other apparent action. 
It has since had a bit of an edit and the flagged comment removed.

Image of earlier status:

[image: The question has English issues, one Community-bot comment asking for details, and one comment/vote for a duplicate]

---

At the absolute other end of the scale, ***this*** truly deserves the rubber stamp, and I imagine will be closed in minutes. There are degrees to this, which people are not caring about. My own comment on this was tailored to suit.

> [image: Unclear question with comment asking if someone reading over the poster's shoulder would be able to understand it.]

…and more for my own savage amusement - completely obvious spam post flagged the same way… for some reason after it was closed:

[image]

These are examples where this capricious rubber stamp is being clearly misused.

Comment: Why do you think someone who can't vote to close left that message? As far as I can tell, a 13k rep user did.

Comment: _"Just because you don't understand the question is no reason to flag it as 'needs detail'"_ isn't a very constructive thing to say, should probably itself be flagged as no longer needed and isn't necessarily accurate (if you don't understand a question, maybe it _does_ need more detail). _"we ought to perhaps be looking towards lessening that propensity"_ - of users engaging in moderation?

Comment: @Catija - then there is little hope. If a 13k user is going to post a rubber-stamp like that, then I guess there's little we can do to make them think harder.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - there's "engaging in moderation" then there's "rubber-stamping something you don't understand &/or can't be bothered to think through". My linked example above is one where a bit of a syntax tidy-up would have left the question in fine order. I can only assume the reviewer didn't know what Onetab was, nor how to go about finding that out - in which case they should have skipped the review. There was nothing in the question incomprehensible, it was merely clumsily-worded, by a non-English native.

Comment: Again, not understanding something is a good reason to say it's unclear. Poor English can contribute to that, as the reviewer may themselves not be a native speaker. But things like _"can't be bothered to think through"_ and _"I can only assume..."_ suggest you're not interested in engaging constructively at all. Users who want to move past "I can has answers/points?" and engage in the activities that keep these sites running are rare enough already; if they're not doing it well, I'd say the focus should be on helping them understand what better looks like not stopping them entirely.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - and how do we achieve that? perhaps remove the less-contructive of the rubber stamps. Whether the reviewer didn't understand the English or didn't know what Onetab was doesn't make a difference. Not understanding does not in itself mean it is unclear, merely that the reviewer did not understand. They are not necessarily one & the same thing. Do you, personally, understand the question as it was originally written? Do you know what Onetab is? Would you look it up if not, or rubber-stamp it?

Comment: Here's a [relevant meta](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1629/please-take-the-time-to-tailor-write-comments-for-new-users-questions) I recently raised on Lit Meta

Comment: @bobble - excellent link. Shows someone took the time to make their own comment & even if it is copy/paste from a list of 'relevant responses' it is still considerably more helpful than the bot comment, which shows total disregard for the OP.

Comment: Writing comments that are clear, appropriate and sensitive to a multinational, multilingual audience is incredibly hard, takes significant time, with all sorts of risks of getting it wrong. Rubber stamping uses a wording which you can point at as company approved (not your fault if its perceived as rude), requires minimal time, and doesn't require a deep understanding of the issues. It seems pretty clear to me why people would choose the second given all the barriers to giving feedback.

Comment: @user1937198 - I'm sure that's my entire point. How can we encourage people to actually give valid feedback, or just skip the review if they don't understand it, rather than rubber-stamp?

Comment: @Tetsujin: my implied comment was that the cost benefit for reviewing at all doesn't really work unless you rubber stamp. So either it needs to be a lot easier/less risky to write comments. (Which probably means accepting people will write comments that don't meet one of the criteria I gave without it being an issue for them). Or we need to have a lot less posts needing review on the big sites that dominate the system.

Comment: @user1937198 - My counter-argument to that would be "If you can't be bothered, don't do it at all, rather than skimp".

Comment: @Tetsujin Right, and I would say the argument I tried to make against that, is that we just don't have enough people willing to do what you regard as a 'proper review' to keep up with the queue on SO. SO barely has enough people to keep up with the queue with rubber stamping. And the way the politics of SE work now, if it would cause issues for SO, its a difficult proposal to push through. So I would say to do this, you need to reduce the number of questions needing closure on SO to the point where we don't need the rubber stamp reviews.

Comment: I have a bunch of more specific copy/pastes I use instead. Again, my point is don't do it at all rather than do it badly.

Comment: @Tetsujin if people don't do it, how are sites like SO supposed to function?

Comment: Presumably, like they already do. You're just arguing for status quo. Put it in an answer so people can vote on it, rather than back & forth in comments. Personally, these comments make more work for me, as I clean up posts, ask pertinent clarification questions. Maybe if I just ignore all these rubber stamps, the OPs will just go away & not bother us any more. Maybe that's a good idea. Fewer users, fewer problems to fix...

Comment: I'm arguing that we can make changes, but that such a change needs to not increase the amount of effort to do a review compared to rubberstamping, if we want to try and restrict our focus to just the review actions specifically without changes to the wider ecosystem of why reviews are needed.

Comment: The superfluous *"[Does anyone know...](https://superuser.com/posts/1694735/revisions)"* belongs on a forum (recorded conversation), not Stack Exchange (Q&A site). [The Stack Exchange sites are ***not*** forums](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) (fora?). They are [think tanks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681). Just use *"What is..."* (or similar).

Answer (score 5):

Well - to some extent the onus is on the person asking the question to make it clear.

I'd argue that making the judgement to whether a question is *clear* is universal - there's no mention of environment (Windows, Linux and so on) or outside a tag, any context of what OneTab runs on. Chrome might store things in different places based on the OS.

In a sense, the OP didn't really give enough information to *definitively* solve the issue. As a reviewer, some improvements could be done, but only the OP would know what OS they were running.

I'd argue the boilerplate comment wasn't inappropriate, but it lacked useful detail, much like the question itself, but it was hardly inappropriate in context.

Comment: I might change the title of this question to "How to encourage 'real' responses from review, rather than rubber-stamp comments"  - feels more positive, perhaps...

Comment: In direct response, my comment was designed to actually provoke response, even though I did leave the rubber-stamp from the close vote. I hoped for either "No it doesn't, I'm on Mac" etc if it didn't fit. New users are far more likely to respond if they perceive to have been misunderstood than if they are told they are misunderstood. Human nature. Rebel against the negative, even if there is zero response if it was indeed a dupe. They went away with an answer even if they didn't complete our pro-forma to acknowledge that. Link as dupe, twice as many search points as entry to future googlers.