# What is the best site to talk about data warehousing?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, database

I am looking for the adequate site for data warehousing topics.
In terms of critical mass, what is better, Database Administrators or generic Stack Overflow? Am I in the best place?

Comment: First things first: _none_ of the sites on this network are forums.

Comment: From the [[forums\] tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/forums/info): _"We are not a forum! Use this tag when discussing external forums and their relation to the Stack Exchange network of sites."_.

Comment: [webapps.se] unfortunately doesn't seem to quite cover it, however they touch on cloud storage in less major ways. I'd have thought [dba.se] would have been best here, but I'm no expert.

Comment: @jonrsharpe what are they then ? :)

Comment: See e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/248731