# A forum to discuss old computers: Where could I ask if anyone else would be interested?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, area-51

My computer will reach the end of its official support in five days. It's a 32 bits architecture, so I can't upgrade it. I have others, including an [Apple II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_II) which belonged to my dad: [5 1/4 inch floppies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floppy_disk#8-inch_and_5%C2%BC-inch_disks), no hard disk, and still functioning.

I read through the requirements for [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) proposals. There would have to be at least five experts for an official forum creation request. I don't know a single one. I'm not an expert; I just fiddle.

Please, where could I post a question of the type "Would anyone be interested in creating a forum to support users of old computers?".

I see two advantages of having such a forum.

First, it would be good for the planet. Some people don't care about being up-to-date; they just want a functional machine. So they only buy a new computer when the old one stops functioning. The old one ends up in some forlorn place where people burn the wires to get copper, thus polluting the surrounding land and air. And building a new computer has a CO<sub>2</sub> cost, of course.

Second, there are questions on Stack Exchange concerning old computers, spread out among several forums ([U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.design/brand/copywriting/naming/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour), etc.). It would be a shame to lose all this knowledge by simply closing or deleting them. It's a part of our collective history we would be losing. Wouldn't it be so much better if there was a way for moderators to simply move the offending questions to the "Old Computers" forum?

Comment: We already have Retro Computing, did you check their help centre: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic ?

Comment: For the record: Posts can only be migrated in the first 60 days after posting. So even if moderators now find posts to be off-topic on their site and on-topic on another, they still can't migrate it. Migration is rare, and needs knowledge of both sites.

Comment: [The Stack Exchange sites are ***not*** forums](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) (fora?).

Comment: Are you asking where you can ask after "old computers" as a topic, and, if so, do you want to know about software or hardware? Or are you asking after a place where you can ask where to create a forum? Or are you asking where such a forum can be created?

Answer (score 16):

We don't have any forums at all - we have Q&A sites.

We *do* have a site for [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com) for your Apple II era old PCs.

Otherwise we support and *still do* support questions all the way back to XP on Super User. We don't close questions for obsolescence either. I recall one 'recent' Win 9x era question as well involving some specialised equipment.

I think there's reasonable coverage without a new site.

Comment: Retrocomputing only accepts questions about old computers — just being EOL isn't enough. Chromebooks, for example, reach their EOL (called Auto Update Expiration) in 5–8 years.