# What's this stack thing all about?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, mac

I'm new to this whole stack thing, and overwhelmed by it all. It seems so spread out and disorganised. I figure that it's about time I figure it out.

Where is the best help for questions about compiling CLI tools, shell scripting and things of that nature on the Mac?

- stackoverflow.com?
- superuser.com?
- apple.stackexchange.com?
- unix.stackexhange.com?

So an article titled "Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?" has been suggested to me. I read it and I'm still not sure if I should be posting in Stack Overflow or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour), but now someone shut down my question and others are downvoting it. So I guess I don't deserve an answer. Not a very approachable site if you ask me. It seems like people are more into the policing aspect of it than actually helping people.

Comment: Please start by taking the [tour] and reading through the help center, and keep in mind that [this is not a discussion forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107).

Comment: How come people answer in the comments like this, instead of using the "Answer Question" button?

Comment: That's because answers consisting only or mostly of just links [are not considered proper answers](/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: even if the link answers the question really well?

Comment: @timelessbeing Indeed.  Answers should be self contained, and not just a copy-paste of an external site(see: Copyright violation).

Comment: so if the answer is 5 pages long, it's better to type it out in one's own words than just post a link to an article that may have done a better job? Not all sites are copyright protected.

Comment: @timelessbeing generally, one would summarize the key aspects of the answer to make it self-contained, while linking to the original source. That way the full details *should* be available, but the answer stands on its own in the event of link rot. You can certainly also quote sections from a source but 5 pages is very excessive