# Question got deleted by accident?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation, deleted-questions, flag-weight

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624837/hyperlink-does-nothing-when-clicked) from [CoffeeAddict](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93468/coffeeaddict) got deleted yesterday, possibly following [my flag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-weight/165154) (the link is only for moderators) saying:

> It is eligible to be reopened again IMHO

The question was (successfully) voted to be closed initially, but when the user (or another community member) expanded the question (based on additional information from a duplicate question posted by the same user shortly after the above question was closed), I voted to reopen again.

As I saw the question was not voted to reopen again soon enough (perhaps because it lost attention from he community) I flagged it for moderator attention to be reopened again.

However, as you can see in my flag history, my flag was deemed helpful, but the question was closed none-the-less.

So I believe basically either of the following is the case:

- my flag **was not** helpful, or
- my flag **was** helpful, and the question shouldn't have been delete but reopened again

Comment: [The question in question is the subject of this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108125/145673). It was deleted by three 20K+ users not a moderator.

Comment: And _very_ deliberately I might add, no accident here.

Comment: That user got into a frenzy, see what's written in his About Me box. This alone might have led people to downvote/close/delete the question. He also posted dozens of offensive comments, which got deleted.

Comment: Your concept of helpful vs. not helpful is wrong. If you were _trying to be helpful_, and not _completely off base_, the flag should be marked as helpful whether or not it was acted upon.

Answer (score 1):

> ...but when the user (or another community member) expanded the question (based on additional information from a duplicate question posted by the same user shortly after the above question was closed)...

I'd guess that the question was deleted because there's a duplicate with more information.

Comment: … shouldn't it be closed as a duplicate / merged then?

Comment: @slhck: Possible, but why keep it if there's a duplicate with more information from the same user around?

Comment: No, they both got deleted unfortunately. Although I must admit: I don't know whether the other question was voluntarily deleted by OP (I've added a link to the user profile in my question now). Can't find the url to the duplicate anymore.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of a duplicate *posted by the user*. That's different then.

Comment: @fireeyedboy: In that case we've got to wait for a 10k to scan his profile and tell us who deleted the second question.

Comment: Both were deleted by 20k's, first the duplicate, then the original due to the attention it got from meta.  Neither question had improved much and the additional offensive comments left by the asker prompted the deletion.

Comment: @JeffMercado: Can we get that as an answer, please?